# On a CSS hover event, can I change another div's styling?

Tags: css

When I hover over a div or class with an id of "a", can I get the background color of a div or class with the id of "b" to change?

Comment: Using flexbox, you can hover other elements even if they (appear to) be placed *before* the hovered one in the DOM. See my [pure-CSS rating widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered/32470900#32470900).

Answer (score 731, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, but only if `#b` is after `#a` in the HTML.

If `#b` comes immediately after `#a`: http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/

```
#a:hover + #b {
    background: #ccc
}

<div id="a">Div A</div>
<div id="b">Div B</div>
```

That's using the [adjacent sibling combinator](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector) (`+`).

If there are other elements between `#a` and `#b`, you can use this: http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/1/

```
#a:hover ~ #b {
    background: #ccc
}

<div id="a">Div A</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div id="b">Div B</div>
```

That's using the [general sibling combinator](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector) (`~`).

Both `+` and `~` work in all modern browsers and IE7+

If `#b` is a descendant of `#a`, you can simply use `#a:hover #b`.

ALTERNATIVE: You can use pure CSS to do this by positioning the second element before the first. The first div is first in markup, but positioned to the right or below the second. It will work as if it were a previous sibling.

Comment: it should be noted that the sibling selector (+) doesn't work correctly in ie8 and below.

Comment: @thirtydot, pliss to add some explanations like how and why

Comment: @Brock Adams: Someone else inexplicably added the `javascript` tag: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6910049/revisions

Comment: Oops missed that; sorry.  Deleting earlier comment.

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome on Linux/Windows, works in FF{linux/winxp}, Opera{linux} and IE7/8{win xp}, I would have accepted your answer

Comment: Thanks to all who answered. This was the closest to a no jquery solution. Thanks

Comment: Great, its working for me as i had other div's between my target div's. Thank you very much.

Comment: is there a way of affecting #a when #b is hovered over? I tried http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/1829/ but that does not work

Comment: Interesting, thanks @thirtydot. Does either operator work on an immediately nested element? (such as `<div id = "asdf"><div id = "affect_this_element?">...</div></div>`)

Comment: @IanCampbell: Like `#asdf:hover > #affect_this_element`?

Comment: Cool, the child selector `>` works, thanks @thirtydot!

Comment: i have a doubt what ever style they include in the hover state i think it should apply for parent plus child.How come here it is applying for child alone. Can anybody help me?

Comment: @sun: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: if i understand correctly on hover of `a` tag you are selecting its preceding element so that styles are applied to the preceding elements. Am i right? @thirtydot

Comment: @sun: Which CSS selector are you talking about?

Comment: Adjacent sibling combinator and Child combinator @thirtydot

Comment: @sun: What is the actual CSS selector you're asking about (for example `#a:hover + #b`)? There is no way in CSS to *select* the preceding element (or the parent element). `a + b` selects `b` if it *immediately follows* `a`. There is no way to do the reverse, select `a` if there is `b` *immediately following* it.

Comment: sorry its my english fault i shouldn't have stated precede there. ok is that possible to give style for body tag on hover of other element ofcourse it is parent of other div and a. But is there any bypass way there? @thirtydot

Comment: @sun: Not with pure CSS, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: i am trying to do the same thing but on target(to simulate on click event) and not on hover but it doesn't work. do you know why?

Comment: @thirtydot -- I'm wondering, when both `#a` and `#b` is within a separate wrapper div, the hover over effect does not work. Any CSS-based solution that can somehow get this to work? (An example might be something like: **A**`<div class="wrapper01"><div id="a">Div A</div></div>` and **B** `<div class="wrapper02"><div id="b">Div B</div></div>`) I have set up a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/mu86yj6f/

Comment: @kenhimself: Unfortunately, there's no CSS based solution with HTML like that, the elements must be siblings. Time to use JavaScript.

Comment: Is it possible to effect the element before the hovered one?
For example :  `<div id="a">Div A</div>`
                        `<div id="b">Div B</div>`
Hovering on #b change #a.

Comment: just to note, it works with classes as well `.level:hover + .levelEnd { border-left: thin solid #808080; }`

Comment: Using flexbox, you can hover other elements even if they (appear to) be placed *before* the hovered one in the DOM. See my [pure-CSS rating widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered/32470900#32470900).

Comment: I am trying to do this backwards too, so horvering #a affects #b, and hovering #b affects #a, although this seem to not work the same way... What should I do here?

Comment: This solution is great but sucks at the same time!  I want B to affect A without repositioning everything in CSS.  It seems "adjacent" siblings are not really "adjacent" if you can only affect the second element with the first.  Seems like B is really a sibling of A no matter what based on the DOM.  maybe JS is the best solution for me.

Comment: Awesome, Didn't know this cool stuff before. Was overloading my page with JQuery alternatives till now. Thanks again.

Comment: How do I do the opposite of `#a:hover #b`? So when I hover over the child, the parent gets styled.

Comment: @facepalm42: In general, that's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/405015).

Comment: it seems like it doesn't work if the hoverable element is inside a <th> inside a table, so weird

Comment: I've been here a million times already, and if I could upvote this every time I came here, I would.

Comment: Salute to this answer. Worked like a charm!!! I'll give you million upvotes!!

Comment: This is a cheat sheet I always use when it comes to very precise css selection

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.php?

Works liek acharm and you can see what operators to use to target a specific element you may have

Answer (score 37):

This can not be done purely with css. This is a behaviour, which affects the styling of the page.

With jquery you can quickly implement the behavior from your question:

```
$(function() {
  $('#a').hover(function() {
    $('#b').css('background-color', 'yellow');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $('#b').css('background-color', '');
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes it can, albeit only under relatively limited situations. But this can certainly be done with CSS.

Comment: @David yes only in limited situations where #b is a child or sibling of #A, etc. The OP didn't specify the relationship between the two, so I assumed this wasn't the case.

Comment: Using flexbox, you can hover other elements even if they (appear to) be placed *before* the hovered one in the DOM. See my [pure-CSS rating widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered/32470900#32470900).

Comment: Bumped for including mouseout reset

Answer (score 18):

A pure solution without jQuery:

### Javascript (Head)

```
function chbg(color) {
    document.getElementById('b').style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

### HTML (Body)

```
<div id="a" onmouseover="chbg('red')" onmouseout="chbg('white')">This is element a</div>
<div id="b">This is element b</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YShs2/

Comment: You don't even need onmouseover. See my [pure-CSS rating widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered/32470900#32470900).

Comment: @DanDascalescu this is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: How to use that on SCSS?

Comment: This is the only solution here that worked for me. I was even able to tweak the function a bit to allow for the target element to be a parameter as well. Thank you so much @kongr45gpen!

Answer (score 10):

The following example is based on jQuery but it can be achieved using any JS tool kit or even plain old JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#a").mouseover(function(){
         $("#b").css("background-color", "red");
     });
});
```

Comment: [tag:css] ***not*** [tag:jquery] (or [tag:javascript]).

Comment: jquery is the most adequate solution here.

Comment: Then at the very least offer an explanation of why css is inadequate, and what the other, more suitable, options are. I don't think that just throwing a jQuery solution into the question is particularly useful.

Comment: jQuery is a extension of javascript. The user never specifically asked for no jQuery solution.

Comment: jQuery is most adequate as most people know it, though you can use some other toolkit as well

Comment: He also didn't specifically ask for a 'no-[tag:python]' solution, but given that the question was tagged with *only* '[tag:css]', it seems fair to assume that he wanted a css solution.

Comment: Fair point @David Thomas, at the time of posting this answer, javascript was a tag, so i assumed a javascript solution would be acceptable

Comment: Ah, yeah. I saw that tag was added (though I hadn't seen it until after I posted my first comment). I was about to retract my initial comment when I realised that it'd been removed in another edit (since it wasn't the OP that added the [tag:javascript] tag). Sorry if I seem unduly...uh... *contentious*, it's not intended as hostility. Also, it's worth pointing out that the down-vote wasn't mine, I accept your answer is useful, it's just not what was asked-for, I think.

Comment: If I had come to this question with only a CSS tag I wouldn't have posted a javascript/jquery solution, as the user may be after a solution which works with or without javascript. No problem, you don't seem hostile, its good to see people are re-enforcing that jquery shouldn't just be used as a quick solution when its not even asked for!

Comment: Thanks for adding solution for jQuery too. It helped me.

Comment: while a JS/JQuery solution IS helpful, I too agree that `CSS:hover` and `JS.mouseover()` are 2 completely different things.

Comment: Javascript is less performant than CSS, therefore css is a more desirable solution in a professional project.