# how to rotate image when hover another div?

Tags: css

CODE HTML :

```
<div class="images-rotate">
 <a href="link login">
   <img class="rotate" src="http://localhost/design/images/h_login.png" width="100px" /> 
 </a>
</div>


<div class="ABC">
 <p>
  HELLO WORLD !
 </p>
</div>
```

CODE CSS :

```
.rotate{
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s; 
-moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
transition-duration: 0.8s;

-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform; 
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
-o-transition-property: -o-transform;
transition-property: transform;

overflow:hidden;

} 

.rotate:hover 
{
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); 
-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
-o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

With this code, when i hover IMAGE class "rotate", it will rotate 360deg.

But now i want : when user hover div class "ABC", IMAGE will auto rotate 360deg.

How to do it ?
Someone can help me.
Thank you very much !

Comment: look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling

Answer (score 2):

Put hover effect in a class `hovered` and use this jQuery code:

```
 $(".ABC").on('hover',function() {
           $("img").toggleClass("hovered");
        });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KT3gL/) is a working example.

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/KT3gL/2/

Comment: Can you help me step by step !
Thank

Comment: Now when i hover "Hello world" image rotate,
BUT when i hover image it cannot rotate.

How to fix it ?
Thank !

Comment: i updated my answer. please consider accepting my answer if everything is ok for you :)

Comment: thank, i add css :

.rotate:hover 
{
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); 
-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
-o-transform:rotate(360deg);
} 


and it can rotate when i hover images or div class ABC.


Can you give me your contact: facebook or gmail... thank ?

Comment: now i am studying web design, I see you are fluent in jquery... you can help me something about jquery in future.

Sorry if it make you mind!

Comment: have something wrong, i added that code into website. when i hover div class ABC, all img rotate, i want only img in div class "image-rotate" rotate.
Can you help me how to do that !

Comment: change with $("div.image-rotate img").toggleClass("hovered");

If u want to learn how to use jQuery I suggest you to study the jQuery module from http://www.codecademy.com/

Answer (score 0):

try this :

http://jsfiddle.net/KzFL4/5/

CSS :

```
.ABC p{
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s; 
-moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
transition-duration: 0.8s;

-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform; 
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
-o-transition-property: -o-transform;
transition-property: transform;
    cursor:pointer;
   overflow:hidden;
 } 

.ABC p:hover 
{
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); 
-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
-o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```