# Targeting an element by hovering another element in CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I target one element on hover and then effect an other element?

Here's the **HTML:**

```
        <header>
            <h1 style="float: left; margin-top: 2%;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Naughty Mama.</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="profile.php">My Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="inbox.php">Inbox</a></li>
                    <li><a href="notifications.php">Notifications</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Here's the **CSS:**

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

header {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

nav {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

I want to effect the `nav ul li` when I hover on `nav ul li a`.

Hope I am clear.

Comment: There is no parent selector in CSS.

Comment: you cannot untill CSS level 4 will be usable .

Comment: possible duplicate of [On a CSS hover event, can I change another div's styling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling)

Comment: This is easily done with JS though.

Comment: I know how to do that with JS but I wanted a CSS solution! :) Thanks. Anyone post the answer so I can accept it :) The first one will be accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may style `<a>` so it covers `<li>`. apply hover effect as background to `<a>` :) 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zyDLA

```
header {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eee;
  vertical-align:top;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display:block;
  padding:15px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background:#48a
}
```