# CSS Only - make first element change colour when :hover over any sibling

Tags: html, css

I want solution using **only CSS**

we have 3 circle here.

Whenever I perform mouse-over on circles with class Name Mycircle , the circle with class Name BigCircle should change to red color

html

```
<div class="BigCircle"></div>
<div class="mycircle"></div>
<div class="mycircle"></div>
```

CSS

```
.mycircle,.BigCircle{width:50px; height:50px; border-radius:30px; background-color:grey; margin:3px}
.mycircle:hover{background:yellow}

.mycircle:hover .BigCircle{background:red}
```

Here is the demo >http://jsfiddle.net/JGbDs/4/

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can the order of the `div` in the HTML be modified? I mean are you looking for a pure CSS solution without changing the markup? If the mark-up can be changed, you can try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JGbDs/5/).

Comment: @Harry   no.. i want the same order, but if you want you can add some html elements

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your comments you state that you cannot re-arrange the elements, but you can add ones if required.

For that reason the general sibling combintor in the accepted answer is not suitable as the `.bigCircle` element would have to come **after** all of the `.myCircle` elements.

There is no perfect way of achieving this using only CSS but it is possible by adding a "parent" element and using one of the following CSS solutions:

### Solution 1

When hovering on the parent element, the `.bigCircle` child element will be coloured red:

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/CKRef/**

#### HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="bigCircle"></div>
    <div class="mycircle"></div>
    <div class="mycircle"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
/* Add float to parent to fit width to content */
.parent {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

.parent:hover > .bigCircle{ 
    background: red;
}
```

The issue with this solution is that the `.bigCircle` element will be coloured red when you `hover` anywhere on the parent, not just on `.myCircle`. Adding the float reduces this effect - but if you hover just outside of the circle then the `.bigCircle` will still be red.

### Solution 2

Using the parent element as a `relative` container, we can add a new element to the page using the `after` pseudo selector when a `.myCircle` element is hovered over:

**Working example http://jsfiddle.net/CKRef/1/**

#### HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="mycircle"></div>
    <div class="mycircle"></div>
    <div class="mycircle"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
/* replaced .bigCircle with mycircle:hover::after */ 
.mycircle, .mycircle:hover::after {
    ....
}

.parent {
    position: relative;
}

.mycircle:hover::after { 
    content: "";
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

The imperfection with this solution is that we are targeting the position of the first child of the parent element, rather than the element with the class name `.bigCircle`. Also, the `after` pseudo selector is **not** supported in IE7.

Answer (score 1):

No. That's not possible using just css. "Any sibling" selector is not there in css.

However, if you can move BigCircle to end, you can use general sibling combinator which can select successor siblings.

```
.mycircle:hover ~ .BigCircle{background:red}
```

Comment: i need the same order as i send. csn u do it??

Comment: I need the same markup, But can you do it by adding a extra html elements