# How to change div color?

Tags: html, css

How can I change `div` `bg color` From when I mouse over the another `div`...??

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.Div1{width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red; float:left; margin-right:30px; }
.Div2{width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#00C; float:left }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Div1">asdlsakd</div>
<div class="Div2">asdsa</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to change color of div1 to yellow when i mouse over the `div2`  how can I???

This is my fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/anupkaranjkar/S5Yu5/

Comment: If I am not wrong from your question, you have two overlapping divs, div1 and div2 and you want to hover on them to get a yellow color? Is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean i want to change color of div2 when I hover mouse to div1...??

Comment: `I want to change color of div1 to yellow when i mouse over the div2 how can I???` You want on both div or only one div - @AnupKaranjkar ?

Comment: I updated my answer to match your HTML code.

Comment: only on div1..!! and how can i check

Comment: possible duplicate of [On a CSS hover event, can I change another div's styling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery way:

Try to use `jQuery` `.show();` and `.hide();` function.

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">This is div1</div>
<div id="div2">This is div2</div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}

#div2{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#div1").hover(function() {
    $("#div2").show();
    }, 
function() {
    $("#div2").hide();
});
```

Don't forget to link to `jquery.min.js`.

Add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>` to your `<head></head>` tag. Otherwise it won't work.

Have a look at this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2a9Q/1/)**

**EDIT:**

Pure CSS:

Put a container around your divs like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="div1">This is div1</div>
    <div id="div2">This is div2</div>
</div>
```

after that you can use `:first-child` and `:hover` in this way:

```
//styling your divs
#div1{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}

#div2{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    display:none;
}

//hover function
#content > div:first-child{
    display:block;
}

#content > div:hover + div {
    display:block;
}
```

If you want to see it in practise have a look at this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MjLkH/1/)**

Comment: reason of downvote? If you vote down please tell me the reason so I can help better next time.

Comment: this is perfect but I dont want to use of any other language, Just using html or css...!! please try

Comment: You are cracking a nut with a sledgehammer here. What OP's asking can be achieved without any JS at all, set aside using libraries like jQuery.

Comment: @Pavlo okay thanks for your comment, i will remember next time before answering :)

Comment: Hey Roman Thanks Its Solve I like it also ... Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

As the users above state, you should use `:hover` to achieve that. However they gave you an example what to do when you hover the div itself.

Your question was how to change the color if you went Hover the other div, so heres the code, this however implies that the second div is nested into the first div:

```
Div1:hover Div2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Here is an example which is achieved with JQuery where it doesn't matter if they are nested or not:

```
var defaultBackground = $("div#two").css("background-color");
$( "div#one" )
  .mouseover(function() {
      $("div#two").css("background-color", "yellow");
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $("div#two").css("background-color", defaultBackground);
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d58Rb/

---

To match your HTML code, i updated the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/S5Yu5/1/

---

Just in case anyone else ever needs this solution (I don't see it anywhere)

This is possible using CSS/HTML, but only if the divs are directly below eachother.

```
#Div1:hover + Div2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Tested in JSFiddle and you are right. My code implies that the second div is nested into the first. I am not sure if you can change the background of the second div when hovering the first through CSS if they are not linked to eachother. The JQuery example will work tho. Also i updated the JSFiddle, and check the result when the second is nested into the first (The text color will change): http://jsfiddle.net/d58Rb/1/

Comment: thnx its working but friend i want its work only using css or html

Comment: With your current code it is not possible. You would have to nest one of the divs.

Comment: Its possible bro I sor out the Problem thnx for try to help me

Comment: Its possible my friend I can do it...!! I solve my own question..!!

Answer (score 1):

Use Like this:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="width:200px;background:white"  onmouseover="this.style.background='gray';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">
Hello World!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [**`:hover`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/CSS/%3ahover)

```
Div1:hover {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with css

```
Div1:hover {
      background-color:yellow;
}
```

OR

with JQuery

```
$("div").hover(function() { // mouseenter
    $(this).addClass("hover");
    }, function() { // mouseleave
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

css

```
.hover {
      background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select and style every  element that are placed immediately after  elements:

```
 .first:hover +div{background:red;}  
    <div class="first"> 
          some    
      </div>
      <div>other</div>
```

Example2

```
   .first:hover div{background:red;}

   .first{border:1px solid blue;width:100px;height:100px}

      <div class="first"> 

          <div>other</div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to make a div2 to achive this.

```
Div1{width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red; }
Div1:hover{width:100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; }
```

Just apply `:hover` pseudo selector to your existing div1 and you will get the hover effect.