# CSS combinator precedence

Tags: css, operator-precedence, combinators

I wish to make alterations to a div named rightPanel when either itself, or another div named "plus", is hovered.

```
div#plus:hover, div#rightPanel:hover ~ #rightPanel {

    // make changes to rightPanel
}
```

(The current combinators are not working). How can I organise the precedence of the combinators to have the effect of (div#plus:hover, div#rightPanel:hover) ~ #rightPanel?

Comment: the question is #rightPanel inside #plus? what are the relation between them

Comment: Give us the HTml please

Comment: This issue is related to - 

[hover an element to change another divs styling][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then, you want rightPanel to update if you hover over it, or plus - so, try:

```
#rightPanel:hover,
#plus:hover ~ #rightPanel{
 background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

it will handle the hover on rightPanel and delegate the hover over plus

Answer (score 0):

if you want to prioritize a bit of css, you can use !important - but as I'm not entirely sure what you're asking this may not answer your query.

example:

```
#div {
font-size:22px !important
}
```