# How to make image appear upon hover over text using css?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of text and I want a small image appears on the side to it when a user hovers over it each line of text. I already tried making the image "visibility:hidden" and then on hover over the link text "visibility: visible," but it does not work for me. Help please.

JSFiddle link: **http://jsfiddle.net/ML9wT/2/**

edit: the link.

HTML

```
<ul class="song-links">
    <li id="track-one"><span class="num-color">1.</span>
    <a href="#">one<div class="song-selector"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25"></img></div></a>
    </li>


    <li id="track-two"><span class="num-color">2.</span>
    <a href="#">two<div class="song-selector"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25"></img></div></a>
    </li>

    <li id="track-three"><span class="num-color">2.</span>
    <a href="#">three<div class="song-selector"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25"></img></div></a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

CSS

```
.song-links {
letter-spacing: 1px;
list-style: none;
color: black;
visibility: visible;
}

.song-selector {
display: inline;
margin-left: 8px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [On a CSS hover event, can I change another div's styling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling)

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work for me"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
.song-links {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  list-style: none;
  color: black;
}

.song-selector {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 8px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.song-links li:hover .song-selector {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, I hid the images with `display: none`. On link hover, they switch to `display: inline`

Also, you do not need opening and closing img tags. Img is a self-closing tag.

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w8H2P/2/

```
<ul class="song-links">
<li id="track-one"><span class="num-color">1.</span>
    <a href="#">one<div class="song-selector"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" /></div></a>
</li>

<li id="track-two"><span class="num-color">2.</span>
    <a href="#">two<div class="song-selector"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" /></div></a></li>

<li id="track-three"><span class="num-color">2.</span>
    <a href="#">three<div class="song-selector"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" /></div></a>
</li>
```

```
a img {
    display: none;
}

a:hover img {
    display: inline;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with that :

```
song-links span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

You can see example in this website: [4Stable Life](http://4stablelife.com/)