# style span when focused on form input

Tags: html, css

Small question but, cannot find method to solve this little problem. I have html form

```
 <div id="todolist">
      <span class="add-on">OK</span>
      <input class="addtodo" placeholder="New todo task" name="TITLE"  type="text" >
 </div>
```

in CSS

```
 #post-todo span{   
     color:#aaa;
 }
```

I want to change `color:#333` when focused on `input`,
how do this?

Comment: It's possible with pure css, but only if you put the span after the input.Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling

Comment: Okay interesting, didn't know that method, even though its kind of logical. But its not Browser compatible so unfortunately useless in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible with pure css to change the `span` styling when focussing the `input`. Using the `:focus` selector works only for child elements of the focused one.

But there is a fairly simple javascript jquery method :

```
$("#post-todo .addtodo").focus(function(){
    $("#post-todo .add-on").css("color", "#333");
})

$("#post-todo .addtodo").blur(function(){
    $("#post-todo .add-on").css("color", "#aaa");
})
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/BEeNa/

Answer (score 3):

use `CSS:focus selector`
something like below.

```
     input:focus
     {
        background-color:yellow;
        color:blue;
     }
```

For suppose your `OK` `span` would be placed after the `input` then the below code will work without the help you of the jQuery. Only the `CSS` will do the trick.

```
<div id="todolist">
      <input class="addtodo" placeholder="New todo task" name="TITLE"  type="text" >
      <span class="add-on">OK</span> <!-- span must be after input-->
 </div>

 .addtodo:focus + .add-on
 {
    background-color:yellow;
    color:blue;
 }
```

The `+` in the CSS is used to Matches any element immediately preceded it by a sibling element.

Consider

```
E + F
{
    // code
}
```

Then `Matches any F element immediately preceded by a sibling element E.`

Here is the Demo http://jsfiddle.net/UxZXN/

Comment: `input:focus` will affect only on `input` tag, but not `span` tag

Comment: instead of input u can use the tag.

Comment: This answer is nicer than the jQuery solution. I've tweaked your answer to make it more obvious the span must be afterwards in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

It finally become possible, just *a few* years later...

It is possible with support of [:focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within).

```css
#todolist:focus-within .add-on { color: #aaa; }
```

```html
<div id="todolist">
  <span class="add-on">OK</span>
  <input class="addtodo" placeholder="New todo task" name="TITLE"  type="text" >
</div>
```