# new background image for each menu parent item on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am wondering how to accomplish this. I have a menu that sits in a 500px high container with a background image. I want to be able to change the background image when hovering over a parent menu item. I thought this could be accomplished with something like:

jQuery:

```
$('#elm').hover(
   function(){ $(this).addClass('hover') },
   function(){ $(this).removeClass('hover') }
)
```

Or with a `.toggleClass`

and then just define the background image in the css classes they switch to. I have it all set up for the first menu item in my [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/elitedesignstudios/wR7PN/3/) however it is currently not working. Seems so straight forward I dont see why its not working. Any help would be great....thanks guys.

*i have one function commented out in the example to try it different ways

Comment: Do you mean like: when hover on 'Domaine de Gourjo': one background-image, when hover on 'Our Wines': a different backround image?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking for the large background image to change when you hover on a menu item. Correct?

Comment: Yes thats exactly right. I added a transition effect in the css to make it a clean change as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing something in the code

```
$('.image-changer-hover').toggleClass('image-changer-hover2');
```

should be

```
$('.image-changer-hover1').toggleClass('image-changer-hover2');
```

and the starting of jquery code is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
.....
.....
.....
});
```

this works
http://jsfiddle.net/wR7PN/8/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do...going to try it on the actual website now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just use plain CSS.

```
#elm {
    /*Style when not hovered*/
    background: url(http://placehold.it/200x300);
}

#elm:hover {
    /*Style when hovered*/
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/200/300);
}
```

Comment: I would agree, but I don't think this is what he's looking for. I'm pretty sure he wants the large background image to change on hover.

Comment: @brouxhaha The concept is still the same. I edited the answer so it is even clearer.

Comment: No it isn't. He wants the background image of the parent div to change when he hovers on a menu item. It's impossible to do this with css. If he wanted the background of the li to change, then yes. The answer by @Sam Battat is what the question is looking for.

Comment: By his question's code, he will change the menu item's background. Thic CSS will do the same. He never mentioned the parent element in his question.

Comment: The first two lines say exactly that: "I have a menu that sits in a 500px high container with a background image. I want to be able to change the background image when hovering over a parent menu item." It's confusing, so I've asked for clarification; but since the jsfiddle is trying to change the image on `image-changer-hover1` (the parent div), it's a little more clear what he wants to do.

Comment: Oh sorry, indeed it makes more sense now. I'll upvote @SamBattat's answer.

Comment: No problem. I completely understand why you thought what you did. I had to read it a couple times myself. And a lot of answers like this are simply to use css :hover.

Comment: I mean when you hover on 'Domaine de Gourjo': one background-image, when hover on 'Our Wines': a different backround image.

Comment: @brouxhaha: It is not *impossible* with CSS. [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20703896/1968548)

Comment: @Sukminder: Right, but with the provided HTML and without moving anything around and/or adding additional elements, it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a quick jsFiddle, which should solve your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2a6Rg/

Everytime you hover over a li, a class specified by `data-element` gets added to its parent, so you can change backgrounds by using CSS.

Important code is:

```
$('#nav li').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass($(this).data('element'));
    },
    function() {
        $(this).parent().removeClass($(this).data('element'));
    }
);
```