# Hover on element A, change the style of element B with fade out animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible when I hover on  A, change the  B's style with fade out animation?
Such as:

```
<div id="A">Div A</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div>random other elements</div>
<div id="B">Div B</div>
```

I want to fade out the B's color from white to red in 2 seconds when I move my cursor to A?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling), it works good but there's no animation when the hover event happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#B{
    background:orange;
}
#A:hover ~ #B {
    transition: background 2s ease;
    background: #fff
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r3hwn/

Answer (score 1):

CSS transtition: [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)

For example:

```
#A {
   transition: 2s background ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have updated the fiddle which is mentioned in the example you gave. http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/3461/

Added transitions to it

```
transition: background 2s ease;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you have two options, option 1, CSS or option 2 jQuery.

Option 1 :

```
#A {
    transition:all 2s;
}

#A:hover < #B {
    color:red;
}
```

Option 2:

```
$("#A").onmouseover(function(){
    $('#B').animate({color: 'red'}, '2000');
}
$("#A").onmouseexit(function(){
    $('#B').animate({color: 'white'}, '2000');
}
```