# Changing background color on nested element using CSS a:hover

Tags: css

I am trying to change the background color of both the #box and #internalArrow elements in the following script by using the a:hover {background-color: rgb(189, 64, 132);} construct.

This is what I have;

```
     <style type="text/css">  
     #box
     {                  
        background-color: rgb(217, 9, 122);
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;  

        position: absolute;               
        top:50%

    }

    #box:after {
        content: ' ';
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;        

        border: 20px solid transparent; 
        border-right-color: #ffffff;

        top: 50%;
        left: 10%;
        margin-left:-15px;
        margin-top:-20px;
    }      

    #internalArrow
    {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        position:absolute;

        border: 20px solid transparent; 
        border-right-color: rgb(217, 9, 122);       

        top: 50%;
        left: 10%;
        margin-left:-5px;
        margin-top:-20px;      
        z-index:100;            

    }

    #box:hover + #internalArrow
    {
        background-color:rgb(189, 64, 132);
    }

    #wrapper
    {
        height:600px;   
        width:50px;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        opacity:0.9;
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="box">        
    <a id="anchor" href=""><div id="internalArrow"></div></a>        
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

I used this previous answer [On a CSS hover event, can I change another div's styling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling) but it doesn't work for me. I have tried it in Chrome and Firefox.  Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Take out the + and that should work

Answer (score 2):

In your css you have:

```
#box:hover + #internalArrow
    {
        background-color:rgb(189, 64, 132);
    }
```

When multiple CSS Selectors should be denoted by a `,`

```
#box:hover, #internalArrow:hover
    {
        background-color:rgb(189, 64, 132);
    }
```

EDIT: Sorry I just reread your question and you were on the right track for changing an element's background, but you used the notation of `+` which is the adjacent sibling combinator.

All you need to do is remove the '+' and do this:

```
#box:hover #internalArrow
        {
            background-color:rgb(189, 64, 132);
        }
```

This denotes that `#internalArrow` is contained by `#box`, the '+' only works if it FOLLOWS `#box`

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/3685/)

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't work for me.  Maybe it has something to do with using the :after selector.  Thanks though.

Comment: Hey @Welshboy I was able to get it working: http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/3685/

All I did was changed the selector to `#box:hover #internalArrow` because `#internalArrow` is contained INSIDE `#box`. See edited bost

Comment: Hi Ryan, I did go to that site before I posted and I have tried those combinations but it doesn't work for me.  I'll keep on trying.  Thanks.

Comment: Yep. I've tried that aswell but doesn't give the required effect.  Obviously I have to do something with the :after selector aswell.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

```
.box .internalArrow {
    background-color: #whatever
};
```