# CSS hover doesn't work

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm quite new to HTML and CSS and I know this is probably a very dumb question but I've been trying to solve it for a while and I can't figure out what's wrong.

I want one div to change its backgound-color when the mouse enters another element not related to it (when the div is the child of the other component it works fine).

My HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>

    </nav>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}

div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 500px;
}

 nav:hover div {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I've tried changing the "nav:hover div" rule for something like "nav:hover body > div" but it doesn't work either...

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `nav:hover div` means a `div` nested in the `nav` while being `hovered`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [On a CSS hover event, can I change another div's styling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling)

Comment: Yes, it's the same question... sorry

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+`:

```
nav:hover + div {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/epu44/)**

The rule you had tried, `nav:hover div`, was looking for divs that were descendants of a nav. You wanted the sibling.