# change other element when mouse over in CSS

Tags: css

i want to change other element outside current element level in CSS3. i have tried to use plus symbol but still not working.

```
    <div id="a">
<div id="a_1">
<ul>

<li>test1</li>
<li>test2</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="b">
</div>
```

i want to change #b background-color i try this but not still work

```
a ul li:hover #b{
background-color:blue;
}
```

and also tried this but not working too

```
a ul li:hover + #b{
background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific to your query?

Comment: Outside current element as in next to it or before it? Modifying an element above the current one will not be possible with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use JavaScript or JQuery for that.

Comment: is this possible to use just pure css

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling