# is it possible to take effect on above element, even i mouse hover on next element without?

Tags: html, css

am trying to change above div if below one is mouse hovered.

Here is my sample code

```
<div class="mainDiv">
<div class="a">Div A</div>
<div class="b">Div B</div>
</div>

.b:hover ~ .a {
    background: #ccc
}
```

if i mouse hover on b, a's background should be change without using jquery. I mean with simple javascript.

please give me an example

Comment: not possible with css use JS

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes please give me one example

Comment: or you could do something like this with css http://jsfiddle.net/ozcqt5an/

Comment: refer this..  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6910112/3164682