# Element hidden by default - show on hover with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV element which is hidden by default. But on hover, I want it to be visible.

This is my current CSS:

```
.main-menu .left-footer{
    display: none;
}

.main-menu:hover + .left-footer {
   display: block !important;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="left-footer">
                <small>
                <a href="/support">Support</a> <a href="/terms">Terms of Service</a> <a href="/privacy">Privacy</a> <br />
                &copy; 2015 LittleBux. All Rights Reserved
                </small>
              </div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I am taking example from [**this topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling)

Comment: where is the element with the `.main-menu` class? post all the relevant code please, not only fragments of it.

Comment: Well not knowing what is in `.main-menu` it cannot be empty if `.left-footer` is not shown. If it is you won't be able to 'hover' over it. To get around this you must set a width and height for it and ditch the `+` in your `.main-menu:hover` css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're using conflicting selectors. In the first, `.left-footer` is a child of `.main-menu`. In the second example, it's a sibling.

As you haven't posted the bit of code with `.main-menu` I'm not sure about it's relationship to `.left-footer`, but you need to make the two rules consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you're getting `display` and `visibility` mixed up. `display: none;` makes the element disappear from the document, meaning you can't interact with it. What you want to use instead is `visibility: hidden;`, which makes the element hidden but still keep its place on the page. Try changing the first block of code to the following:

```
.main-menu .left-footer{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.main-menu:hover + .left-footer {
   visibility: visible;
}
```