# Hover on one HTML element effect another

Tags: html, css, hover

I have shop one Prestashop 1.6.0.14 with many products. The main idea is to make opacity on every displayed products in grid eccept the one that has a hover.

Here is my code (simplified):HTML

```
<div id="tab-content">
<ul id="list">
<li class=product></li>
<li class=product></li>
<li class=product></li>
<li class=product></li>
<li class=product></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I found a bit of solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling) but using selectors "+" or "~" effects only containers after the one I have hover on, not those before it. Is there any solution (CSS, JS)? I appreciate any help.

[Here is my website](http://e-patelnie.pl)

Comment: You can achieve that by using the `:not()` selector.

Comment: will you post your css here which you applied currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone beat me to it as I was creating a jsfiddle - use hover on the ul

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uLh9duh6/)

```
ul:hover .product{background: green;}
ul:hover li:hover{background: none;}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like:

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul:hover li {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
ul li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
li{
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  background-color: #eee;
}
li:first-child{
  border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>ipsum</li>
  <li>dolor</li>
  <li>hello</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul:hover li {
  background-color: #000;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

My initial comment to your post was a suggestion to use the `:not()` selector, but it's not a good answer. :)
Here's a solution, it's not very nice, but it's a CSS solution.

Answer (score -1):

There exists an attribute in CSS to do that!

Comment: care to elaborate? or is op supposed to guess?