# on css hover, change the color of another element

Tags: css

I have an element with class name "example", when I hover over that element, I want to change another element with class name "example-title" that is below that element to have the color white. How do I do that using sass/css?

```
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example-title"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe use this treat
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling

Comment: @Patrick.v That one is marked as a duplicate in a chain of duplicates resolving at the one I posted above, no need to share it in addition.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ~ selector like this :

```
.example:hover ~ .example-title { background: red;}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpm8oxb9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+`:

```
.example:hover + .example-title {
    white;
}
```

sass:

```
.example {
    &:hover {
        & + .example-title {
            color: white;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have .example {
    background-color: white


    &:hover {
        background-color: black;
    }
} How do I nest that in?