# CSS Finding a selector thats not a child

Tags: html, css

In the below examples I have 2 div's, What I'm trying to figure out is how to make `.two` green when `.one` is `.active`. Is it possible? [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2hnu70f/)

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}
.one {
  background: red;
}
.two {
  background: blue;
}
.one.active ~ .two {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<directive-one>
  <div class="one active">
    First block
  </div>
</directive-one>
<directive-two>
  <div class="two">
    Second block
  </div>
</directive-two>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this be referencing the directives specifically in css

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}
.one {
  background: red;
}
.two {
  background: blue;
}
directive-one:active ~ directive-two > .two {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<directive-one>
  <div class="one active">
    First block
  </div>
</directive-one>
<directive-two>
  <div class="two">
    Second block
  </div>
</directive-two>
```

You can also just remove the directives so the divs can be accessed

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}
.one {
  background: red;
}
.two {
  background: blue;
}
.one:active ~ .two {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="one active">
  First block
</div>

<div class="two">
  Second block
</div>
```

Otherwise, I dont believe its possible to access a div that isnt a sibling or child, which is the case with the `<div>` inside the `<directive-one>` trying to access another `<div>` inside another `<directive-two>`

Answer (score 1):

If you mark the `directive-one` with `active`, then it is possible to do with this css:

```
directive-one.active ~ directive-two > .two {
  background: green;
}
```

I don't think it is possible to dig into the 'preceding' element though, but not totally sure.