# + operator in CSS not working

Tags: css

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling) question and trying to implement the solution to my problem. [Here(fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/ufecgntt/) is the example. When I hover upon 'Work Grid Image' the 'Work Strategy' div does not show up.
HTML:

```
<span class="work-grid__image">Work Grid Image</span>
<div class="work-grid__images">Work Grid Images
  <div class="work-strategy">
  Work Strategy
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.work-strategy{
  opacity:0;
}

.work-grid__image:hover + .work-grid__images > .work--strategy{
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out .5s;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: I see someone down voted the question. Could he/she please also leave a comment why?

Comment: As you have a typo (misspelled `work--strategy` with 2 hyphens) that cause the selector to not work I guess someone decided to downvote

Comment: I recommend to close or delete this question

Comment: @LGSon: Here is the updated code. Still the text gets displayed without hovering over the other div.
https://jsfiddle.net/ufecgntt/3/

Comment: The fiddle you now posted has a different hover rule than the one you posted in your question, .... so if you just keep the above code as is and change the misspelled `work--strategy` in your hover CSS rule to `work-strategy` it works: https://jsfiddle.net/ufecgntt/5/

Answer (score 1):

You put `.work--strategy` in your css instead of `.work-strategy`. 
Basically, that class does not exist, a simple typo.

Comment: Since there is a specific reason when to close a question, called "typo", we don't answer those, we vote (or flag) to close them, as they don't benefit future users not being a _proper_ coding issue

Comment: Okay, didnt know.