# How to change properties of another object on hover css

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to change the properties of another object in css but am not sure if I am doing this right. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
ul.drop-menu {
  opacity: 0.1;
}

nav > ul > li:hover ~ ul.drop-menu {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Test
            <ul class="drop-menu">
                <li class="1">Test1</li>
                <li class="2">Test2</li>
                <li class="3">Test3</li>
                <li class="4">Test4</li>
                <li class="5">Test5</li>
                <li class="6">Test6</li>
                <li class="7">Test7</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: That CSS won't work. `~` is a sibling selector, and a `li` can't be a sibling of a `ul`. Post your HTML too

Comment: check out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling)

Comment: The html is added now @MichaelCoker.

Comment: You're already using the immediate descendent/child selector (indicated by ` > ` ).  What exactly are you expecting ` ~ ` to do in this context?  Why not just use ` > ` again or just a space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~` is a "[general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)", so it will match any element that is a sibling that comes after the element on the left side of the selector.

With your markup, you either just want to remove `~` to target any `ul.drop-menu` that is a child of `li`, or if you want the direct descendent, change it to a `>`. I'm assuming you want the latter, in case you nest multiple `.drop-menu`'s in `li`'s. I added another nested menu and changed your selector a little to demonstrate that.

```css
ul.drop-menu {
  opacity: 0.1;
}

nav > ul li:hover > ul.drop-menu {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Test
      <ul class="drop-menu">
        <li class="1">Test1</li>
        <li class="2">Test2
          <ul class="drop-menu">
            <li class="1">Test1</li>
            <li class="2">Test2</li>
            <li class="3">Test3</li>
            <li class="4">Test4</li>
            <li class="5">Test5</li>
            <li class="6">Test6</li>
            <li class="7">Test7</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="3">Test3</li>
        <li class="4">Test4</li>
        <li class="5">Test5</li>
        <li class="6">Test6</li>
        <li class="7">Test7</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Worked just like I wanted it to. I'm new to front-end dev and I'm not very good with css in general since I just jumped right into it. This won't happen if I take some time out of my day to look at things like this though.

Comment: @alexo1001 word up. fwiw, `~` is a general sibling selector, and it's partner in crime is `+`, which is an adjacent sibling selector. Doesn't really apply to your answer, but if you're in a learning mood... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Comment: Thanks, I'll go and check it out @MichealCoker

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `>` instead of `~`. Please check this:

```css
ul.drop-menu {
  opacity: 0.1;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > ul.drop-menu {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Test
            <ul class="drop-menu">
                <li class="1">Test1</li>
                <li class="2">Test2</li>
                <li class="3">Test3</li>
                <li class="4">Test4</li>
                <li class="5">Test5</li>
                <li class="6">Test6</li>
                <li class="7">Test7</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The other guy posted it first though so I selected his answer.