# javascript eventlistener on multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made an EventListener for a few `<div>` elements, now i want do change the opacity on a child of this specific element to change if the EventListener is true on this specific element. How do I write that with jQuery or Javascript? I already wrote the pseudoquote, which I think should work. I have a problem to translate it to js.

```js
var overLay = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay");

for (i = 0; i < overLay.length; i++) {
  overLay[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
  overLay[i].addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);
}

function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("project_07").style.maxWidth = "20px"; //just for testing works!
  /* PSEUDOCODE
  if overlay[i] (mouseover === true) {
    getChildElement of (this/ overlay[i]) // is an <img> element
    and .style.opacity = ".8";
  */
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("project_07").style.maxWidth = "100%";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you just changing styles with mousein/out? If so, css alone will suffice, no need for javascript.

Comment: <div class="i_cell photography"><div class="overlay">Project 09</div><img src="img/Photography.jpg" alt="Project 09"></div>

I want to change the opacity of the ´img´ if the ´div´ with the class overlay is hovered. how to I write that in css?

Comment: You can use adjacent sibling combinator + per [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With event listeners, you can use `this` to reference the current element. Because the handler will only react when during a mouseover event, you don't need to check it because it will always be true.

```
function mouseOver() {
  this.querySelector("img").style.opacity = 0.8;
}
```

Then, if you want to clear the style change on mouseout, just add the same code to your mouseOut function.

```
function mouseOut() {
  this.querySelector("img").style.opacity = 1;
}
```

Also, if you are only modifying the style of child elements, you could solve this with just css.

```
.overlay:hover img {
  opacity: .8;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't css `hover` suffice for this?

Comment: Thats a good point. I just assumed he would add other code, but if its only the one style change then js is unnecessary.

Comment: I'm assuming he's new and doesn't know that instead :)

Comment: No, because I can't choose the nextSibling in CSS?! I have an ´<img>´ covered with an ´<div>´ (in the div is text), if i ´hover´ the ´div´i want to change the opacity of the <img>. is there a way in css?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but there is a sibling selector. Maybe something like `.overlay:hover + div img` would work.

Comment: I basicly want to change the opacity of the ´img´ if the ´div´ with the class ´overlay´ is hovered <div class="i_cell photography"><div class="overlay">Project 09</div><img src="img/Photography.jpg" alt="Project 09"></div>

Comment: @Will Reese: If the dom is like '<div class="i_cell photography"><div class="overlay">Project 09</div><img src="img/Photography.jpg" alt="Project 09"></div>', then 'this.querySelector("img")' would not work because 'img' is not [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) of overlay, rather, sibling, would it?

Comment: @Treefish Zhang In this case, no. Instead you could do something like: `this.parentNode.querySelector("img")`

Comment: Thanks to all! Yes, i tried it instead of ´querySelecter' with ´nextElementSibling´ so it worked. But i got it now with CSS, totally overseen this.

Answer (score 0):

When event is fired you can access the event prameters. It goes to function as n attribute.

One of properties of the event is target - element that fireв event.

```
function mouseOver(e) {
  e.target.querySelector('img').style.maxWidth = "20px";
}
```

Try to console.dir(e.target) and research it.

Answer (score 0):

I will simply suggest: 
1.assign class to all divs you want to have child change opacity
let's say myClass

```js
$('.myClass').children().on('mouseenter', function(){
  $(this).css('opacity', '0.8');
 });
```