# Changing CSS Style for First Column in Table when Hovering over Second Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I've tried so many things to get this work.

Here's the table and CSS code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNereG

You can see, if you hover in the first column, the dotted border is gone. Go over to the second column, it remains.

Learned some things [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling) which talked about `#a:hover + #b` `#a:hover ~ #b` `#a:hover #b`

Generally speaking I'm targeting these elements with like `table.spectable td` for all the TD Rows and Columns, so `table.spectable tr:hover td` worked great on hover for these elements.

The issue is right here:

```
table.spectable td:nth-child(1) {
        border-right: 1px dotted #C1C3D1;
}
```

A dotted line between the columns which is happening on the first column.

Easy to write up a CSS to remove this on hover within the first column :

```
table.spectable td:hover:nth-child(1) {
        border-right: none;
}
```

But if I'm hovering in the second column.. I also want the same thing to occur.

What have I tried? Too many things to list, embarrassingly to say.

As mentioned above,

```
table.spectable td.nth-child(1):hover ~ table.spectable td.nth-child(2) {
    border-right: none;
}
```

was a no go. Same with the `+` variant of that, and the one omitting anything in between. No luck. I've tried a bunch of other random things, some of them are still in the CodePen.

Even jQuery solutions I can't get to work. Example of one:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("table.spectable td.nth-child(2)").hover(function(){
  $("table.spectable td.nth-child(1)").css('border-right','none')
})
</script>
```

I'm sure this is probably really simple.. but how in the world do I get rid of the border in the first column when hovering over the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS selector already exists in your code. 
Add border-right: none; to the following tags:

```
table.spectable tr:hover td {
  background:#7F8C9A;
  color:#000000;
  border-top: 2px solid #22262e;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #22262e;
  border-right: none;
}

table.spectable tr:nth-child(odd):hover td {
    background: #34495E;
    color: #fff;
    border-right: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out https://codepen.io/inijr/pen/EmOEjP?editors=1111

```
for($i = 1; $i < $('.td-cell').length; $i+=2){
     $($('.td-cell')[$i]).hover( 
 function(){
    $('.td-cell').css('border-right','none');
 },
 function(){
    $('.td-cell').css('border-right','1px dotted #C1C3D1');
 });
}
for($i = 1; $i < $('.td-cell-alt').length; $i+=2){
 $($('.td-cell-alt')[$i]).hover(
 function(){
   $('.td-cell-alt').css('border-right','none');
 },
 function(){
   $('.td-cell-alt').css('border-right','1px dotted #C1C3D1');
 });
}
```