# Changing the style of one div when hovering over another

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out why the background of classes 'b' aren't changing when hovering over class 'a', as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling). How can I get this to work? I'd also like it to work with the a tag.

Thanks for any help!

```css
.a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}
.b {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.a:hover + .b {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <span class='b'>here</span>
  <span class='b'><a href='http://www.google.com'>here</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: If your CSS isn't working then it's - mostly - a problem with the selectors you're using, and if your selector isn't working it's always a good idea to look at the W3's documentation for selectors: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong selector, you should be using the *direct child combinator* or `>` instead since `span`'s are inside the `div`:

```css
.a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}
.b {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.a:hover > .b {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <span class='b'>here</span>
  <span class='b'><a href='http://www.google.com'>here</a></span>
</div>
```