# Change another div on hover using only css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change background of div when i hover my link. How can i achieve this? Currently my code looks like this, but it is not working:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 5px;">
     <a id="test" href="">
        <div id="test1" class="col-xs-2 button-left">
           <img class="button-img" src="{{ asset('/img') }}"></img>
        </div>
       <div class="col-xs-5 button-right">
          <h3 style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;">@lang('main.data')</h3>
       </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

```
#test:hover ~ #test1 {
    display: none;
}
```

```css
#test:hover>#test1 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 5px;">
    <a id="test" href="">
      <div id="test1" class="col-xs-2 button-left">
        <img class="button-img" src="{{ asset('/img') }}"></img>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5 button-right">
        <h3 style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;">@lang('main.data')</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `#test:hover > #test1{}`

Comment: Even no need  `>` because it's the only one, also it's children not siblings.

Comment: Ok that works, but only with display:none, but not with background: red and i need bg

Comment: @Promgrma It also works with `background`

Comment: #test:hover > #test1 {
    background: red;
} and nothing happens

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling check this link. You will get idea.

Comment: @Promgrma See the snippet on your post.

Comment: Why this can't work on my page?

Comment: @Promgrma Hard to say, you should inspect. But possible: 1. Override background with `background: red!important` 2. check and sure if it is children.

Comment: important works :) thanks!

Comment: @Pedram another question.. how can i change that h3 color on the same hover? Edit: ok i know, thanks

Comment: @Promgrma Something like this `#test:hover > .button-right h3`