# How to change css of an id element, when hovering over any link in website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Regardless of where the links are in the html, if i hover over one, for example, an image could change, the background could change, or whatever... anywhere in the site.

best answer = simple way without javascript
good enough = elegant way using javascript

---

edit: i already know about this...

```
a:hover ~ #b{
    background: red;
}
```

"~ #b" = next siblings

"+ #b" = first next sibling

" #b" descendant of a

that just effects siblings. what if they have completely different parents?

if there's any neat tricks, website design. that's what i'm looking for.

Comment: Yes it is possible. No it isn't

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling

Comment: any help please?

Comment: As @mplungjan post, there is no way to do it just with CSS. There is a selector `element1 ~ element2` but it only works when element2 is preceded by element1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :hover selector to style elements when you mouse over them.
You can see it  [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp).

Comment: i know how to use simple hovers. i want every link hover, to effect an id.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use JavaScript for that. CSS cannot do this.

```
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
    document.querySelector(".change-on-hover").classList.add("someClass");
}

document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event){
    document.querySelector(".change-on-hover").classList.remove("someClass");
}
```

Change the ".change-on-hover" to a query selector for the element you want to target. "someclass" is the name of a class that will be added or removed when a link is hovered. You'll need to add your desired styles for this class in the CSS.

Comment: i don't know how to get this working. could you give me an example?