# CSS - Table - TH hover set TD visibility

Tags: html, css, less

This seems like it should be straight forward, and I've searched high and low for an answer.

Things to note:

- I'm attempting to make a menu system.  Eventually I'd like to hover a TH to show the TDs below.
- I can't use Class/ID/Name due to limitations (markdown)
- I can only use HTML, CSS, and LESS
- I can't use Javascript or jQuery

I've tried this in a variety of ways, but the code below is a basic example of what I'm attempting to accomplish.

```css
table th:nth-child(1):hover { 
    color: red;
    > td:nth-child(1) { color: red; } 
}
table th:nth-child(2):hover { 
    color: red;
    + td:nth-child(2) { color: red; } 
}
table th:nth-child(3):hover { 
    color: red;
    td:nth-child(3) { color: red; } 
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead><tr><th>Menu 1</th><th>Menu 2</th><th>Menu 3</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>menu 1 item</td>
<td>menu 2 item</td>
<td>menu 3 item</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

When hovering over a a TH, I'd like something to apply to the TD.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: With the HTML structure you've presented (typical table structure), this cannot be accomplished with pure CSS. You can only use `:hover` to affect elements that follow the initial element at the same hierarchy level or a deeper one. Because of that, hovering your `<th>` elements could only affect other elements that come later in the same `<tr>` container unless you use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If the elements are siblings you can use + or ~ but in your case, it seems like they don't have any relationship so you might want to use JS

The question is similar to [On a CSS hover event, can I change another div's styling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling)

Comment: Thank you. I can't use JS, but this referenced question helped me understand that I could at least do it from td(a) to td(b).

Answer (score 0):

Since the `td` elements are not inside the `th` elements and the `th` elements are not at the same level as the `tds`, what you want can't be done with just CSS. Your only choices would either be some type of JS solution or redoing your markup to use `divs` so that you can mimic the table appearance/behavior but control the hierarchy so that the available CSS selectors will work.

Comment: Thanks, this is likely what I'll have to do. I appreciate the info!

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to do this with CSS alone. I created a simple script that can handle adding active classes to the `th` and corresponding `td`:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('th').hover( (e) => {
    const index = $(e.target).index();
    $(e.target).toggleClass('active-row');
    const activeCell = $('tbody td')[index];
    $(activeCell).toggleClass('active-cell');
  });
});
```

```css
.active-row {
  color: red;
}
.active-cell {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Menu 1</th>
      <th>Menu 2</th>
      <th>Menu 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>menu 1 item</td>
      <td>menu 2 item</td>
      <td>menu 3 item</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately, I cannot use JS.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.table td').hover(function() {
      var t = parseInt($(this).index()) + 1;
      $('.table td:nth-child(' + t + ')').addClass('highlighted');
    },
    function() {
      var t = parseInt($(this).index()) + 1;
      $('.table td:nth-child(' + t + ')').removeClass('highlighted');
    });
});
```

```css
.highlighted {
  color: blue;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%">A</td>
      <td width="25%">B</td>
      <td width="25%">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>apple</td>
      <td>banana</td>
      <td>grapes</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>apple1</td>
      <td>banana1</td>
      <td>grapes1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>apple2</td>
      <td>banana2</td>
      <td>grapes2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: We can achieve it by using a simple logic in JS/Jquery.And can give CSS accordingly.

Comment: It could be really helpful to provide some level of explanation to accompany your code to explain why you proposed what you did.

Comment: Here I am taking var t for targetting the columns vertically,Table column indexing start from 0 .So,I am adding  ($(this).index()) + 1; and parsing it into the integer.Suppose If I am hovering on A i.e.first column's first row,then it will target the 1st column of the table.(0)+1.

Comment: RoshniJain, I guess @CollinM.Barrett meant to add the explanations inside your answer. Anyway, OP can't use jQuery or Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there is no solution if you can't use Javascript or jQuery.

⋅
⋅
⋅

Anyway, if you could modify your html structure to be able to use the direct sibling selector,
(I know that it won't be a typical table structure anymore…)
and add some styling, you could achieve that kind of result:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}

table th, table td {
  width: 120px;
  background: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}

table td {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-100%, 100%);
  background: #eee;
}

table th:hover+td,
table td:hover {
  display: block;
}

table th:hover, table td:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Menu 1</th>
      <td>menu 1 item</td>
      <th>Menu 2</th>
      <td>menu 2 item</td>
      <th>Menu 3</th>
      <td>menu 3 item</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Please explain why the downvote. The ones who are using jQuery, which isn't permited are not downvoted… I don't use jQuery and I'm been downvoted! I'd like to understand!

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but it might be due to the modification of the table structure. I cannot remove my TH from the THEAD and place it in the TBODY.