# How to change background of child element when parent element is hovered?

Tags: css

I have the next html structure:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.parent:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

.child {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

How can I change background color of child div when its parent div is hovered? Can I do it with css or I shoud use JQuery?

Comment: I see that many others have answered already. But if you would like to know more consider reading [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```css
.parent {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.parent:hover > .child{
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
.parent:hover .child {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
.parent:hover .child {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.parent:hover {
   background-color: red;
}

.parent:hover .child{
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"> PARENT
  <div class="child">CHILD</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to change

```
.parent:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

to

```
.parent:hover .child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a new rule for .parent:hover .child

Check the example below:

```css
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:blue;
}

.parent:hover,
.parent:hover .child  {
    background-color: red;
}

.child {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.child {
background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```