# Hover an element to change another element which is not a children or sibiling

Tags: html, css, sass

Example code:

```
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

What I want is hovering on box2 to change the style of box1.

Besides do it this way.

```
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box1"></div>

.box2:hover ~ .box1 {

}
```

Is there another solution?

Comment: try to watch this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will delete this question after reading.

Comment: Leo, I have watched your link. I already know "~" only works for sibling. I just want to know is there a way besides edit html.

Comment: I do not understand, the question is if you want to do it another way than css, ie via js, or another way with respect to html?

Comment: I want to do it with only css. Instead of editing html and changing the layout. But it seems impossible.

Comment: but what we have suggested is the correct way, how else would you like to do?

Comment: or you're expressing yourself a little bad, or I'm not understanding a lot