# Css: Trigger a sibling div by hover a button inside div that holds button

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of div(#panel) when I hover the button(#button) that inside in div(#left). Is it possible?

```css
    #left #button:hover~#panel {
            
            background-color: blue;

        }

        #panel {

            position: absolute;
            float: right;
            left: 37.5%;
            width: 50%;
            height: 5px;
            background-color: rgb(180, 30, 30);

        }
```

```html
    <div id="left">
        <button id="button">Topics</button>

    </div>

    <div id="panel"></div>
```

Comment: I think you can't do that without a script. As I recall you can't apply a specific style on an element when you trigger an event on another one.

Answer (score 0):

[There is currently no way to select the parent of an element in CSS.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/5476912)

For you to `:hover` on one element and apply css to other they both need to be on the same level of identation.

[Element you apply css to needs to go before element you `:hover`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6910112/5476912)

Answer (score 0):

If you could, go back and get parent of `#button`(I mean to achieve to `#left`),you can use `+` selector(`#left + #panel`) and change color of `panel`,but unfortunately,there is no **backward** in css, so you can't use pure css and you have to get help from javascript or jquery like this:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {

    $("#button").hover(function() {

        $("#panel").css("color", "red");

    },

    function() {

        $("#panel").css("color", "initial");

    })
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="left">

    <button id="button">Topics</button>

</div>

<div id="panel">Panel</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't quite do it with pure CSS in your example because `#panel` is not a true sibling to `#button`.

Heres a basic script using jQuery...

```js
$("#button").hover(
  function () {
    $("#panel").addClass("hover");
  },
  function () {
    $("#panel").removeClass("hover");
  }
);
```

```css
#button:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

#panel {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  left: 37.5%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(180, 30, 30);
}

#panel.hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <button id="button">Topics</button>
</div>

<div id="panel"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

With CSS, you can actually target sibling elements, only if `#panel` html appears immediately after `#button` html.

```css
#button:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

#button:hover + #panel {
    background-color: blue;
}

#panel {
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    left: 37.5%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(180, 30, 30);
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Topics</button>

<div id="panel"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it if it's not sibling or after or inside the container element, as far as i know.

**You can do it with a simple inline javascript instead:**

```css
#left #button:hover~#panel {

        background-color: blue;

    }

    #panel {

        position: absolute;
        float: right;
        left: 37.5%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: rgb(180, 30, 30);

    }
```

```html
<div id="left">
    <button id="button" onmouseover="document.getElementById('panel').style.background='blue';"
onmouseleave="document.getElementById('panel').style.background='rgb(180, 30, 30)';">Topics</button>

</div>

<div id="panel"></div>
```