# How do I create a motion effect on an icon when hovering over a separate element in Elementor?

Tags: html, hover, elementor

[image: Landing Page Screenshot]

I am trying to create an animation (i.e., transformation) on an element that is triggered by hovering over a separate element. In this case, when the user hovers over the button "Learn More", the top left icon slides right.

This is the part where I might sound stupid so please forgive me:

I named the button class

> .learnmore

and the icon

> .graphic1

I used the inspect tool and found that the button is (I think):

> .elementor-button-wrapper

but it seems to trigger the effect on the entire "row"? I suppose that is what a wrapper is...(so on a side note, I also need help getting the effect to apply when only hovering on the actual button itself lol).

The inspect tool also showed the icon as being (once again, I think):

> .elementor-icon

I somehow managed to create motion effects on both the icon and button when hovering on each of their classes respectively:

```
.learnmore:hover
        .elementor-button-wrapper{
        transform: translateX(1em); 
        }

 .graphic1:hover
        .elementor-icon{
        transform: translateX(1em); 
        }
```

But I can't figure out how to get motion on .graphic1 when hovering on .learnmore.

I thought I could just copy the icon effect and put it under the button class but that didn't work either:

```
.learnmore:hover
        .elementor-icon{
        transform: translateX(1em); 
        }
```

I imagine it has something to do with the elements not being related? I read that they have to be siblings or be a parent-child (once again, I have no idea what I am talking about).

Answer (score 0):

Without your HTML, it's hard to say if this can be solved using pure CSS or if JavaScript is required.

You can try using [CSS Combinators](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp), the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) may work in your case. There's also a [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling) I found which has both a pure CSS implementation as well as a JS version.