# how to change the div background image in mouse over

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to hover over one element and effect a different element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867257/is-there-any-way-to-hover-over-one-element-and-effect-a-different-element)

How to change the div background image,in mouse over the another div,*using css* .

Comment: Where us your code? It depends on the relationship of the elements to determine which selector to use, or resort to JS. Please show your HTML.

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867257/is-there-any-way-to-hover-over-one-element-and-effect-a-different-element

Comment: my code is very simple guys i put it  <a>
    <img src="aaa.png" /> 
    <div style="background-image:url(bbb.png)"> 
    </div>
</a>​ 
i want to change the iv bg while i mouse over the a tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the markup you supplied, this is indeed possible with CSS alone:

```
<a>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /> 
    <div> 
    </div>
</a>​
```

You can use the `:hover` pseudo selector to select the div when the anchor has been hovered

```
a:hover div
{
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/400x400);
}
```

This will change the div's background when the anchor is hovered. This doesn't work in all cases, you must be aware of the relationship of the elements and use the appropriate selector. If the elements have no relationship, you will have to use Javascript (or one of its libraries.)

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/fPGU3/

Comment: thanks Kyle this is work also i prefer this

Answer (score 2):

This will achieve what you're looking for though there are better ways to do this, using sprites and `background-position` for example. However:

Your HTML

```
<a class="selector">My Link</a>
```

Your CSS

```
.selector {
    background-image:url(myImage.jpg);
}

.selector:hover {
    background-image:url(myHoverImage.jpg);
}
```

**Jquery solution**

HTML

```
<a class="selector" data-type="bgChanger1">
    My Link
</a>

<div data-type="bgChanger1">
    ...
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var hoverElement = $('.selector'),

        dataType = hoverElement.attr('data-type'),

        linkedDiv  = $('div[data-type="' + data-type + '"]');

    hoverElement.hover(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault()

        linkedDiv.css('background-image', 'hoverImage.jps');
    },
    {
        linkedDiv.css('background-image', 'normalImage.jpg');
    });
});
```

Comment: no i meant if i mouse over some div the another background image for another div change not same div

Comment: You cant do that directly with CSS alone, you could hack it a bit and put an absolute positioned div that's a child of the hover element, and move that wherever you want though I would just use Javascript...

Comment: Yes, a much better choice for this ^^

Comment: how? do u  have a code for that ??

Comment: @dean You **do not** _need_ to use jQuery for this, please post your HTML and there is a large chance you can do this with CSS alone!

Comment: see the problem is i have <a><img src="123.png" /> <div background-image:(asdas.png)> </div></a> i need in mouse over the a tag the div only inside change the bg image can i do that in css

Comment: @Kyle, sure I havent seen the HTML but he seems to want to change a non child elements css on hover. As far as I am aware that is not possible with CSS alone.

Comment: @dean added rough jquery to achieve what you were requesting in the answer

Comment: @David, with the markup he supplied, it is possible. Dean: gave you an answer free of jQuery.

Comment: He didn't supply any markup still... thanks for your answer it is definitely elegant.

Comment: Thanks :) There was some markup in a comment somewhere. Turned out he was asking about children, so it would work :) +1 for your solution too.

Comment: @ Kyle Sevenoaks thanks man it's work fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to do this.

Your markup:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Your script:

```
$("#div1").mouseover( function() {
   $("#div2").css("background-image", "url('image.png')");
});
```

Comment: thanks man this is simple and easy :) :)

Answer (score 0):

just add a jquery script as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div1').hover(function(){
      $('#div2').css("background","url(image_url)");
    });
 });
```

Comment: This is not a css solution as asked dean.

Comment: i dont think that we can do it with css alone beacause as asked the backgound of another div has to be changed on mouse over to a particular div.so it requires some script.

Comment: Armel,if you get a simpler solution,please do share.