# CSS Hover over something and have a completely different div change its attribute

Tags: html, css

im trying to write a code where you hover over a div and have a completely different div change its effect

heres my code

html

```
    <div class="a">LOREM IPSUM</div>
    <div class="boxhighlight"></div>
```

css

```
    .a:hover, .boxhighlight
    {
        background-color:black;
    }
```

what i want to happen is that when the user hovers over the word lorem ipsum, the div boxhighlight will change its background color

is there a way to do this?

thanks

Comment: Yes ,There is easy way to do it, But please first try Google, and plz tell what u have tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling

Comment: there are already a lot of questions like this. try googling and see stackoverflow faqs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to hover over one element and effect a different element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867257/is-there-any-way-to-hover-over-one-element-and-effect-a-different-element) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling

Answer (score 4):

Use like this

```
<div class="a">LOREM IPSUM</div>
<div class="boxhighlight" >asdf</div>
```

Your css

```
.a:hover ~ .boxhighlight  {
background-color:black;
color: white;
}
```

See this for your [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867257/is-there-any-way-to-hover-over-one-element-and-effect-a-different-element)

See example in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/aeqkm/)

Comment: Excellent answer plz explain ~ meaning

Comment: Because, general sibling combinator (~) selects that element any where eg: http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/bJZJW/. If they want the adjacent element then use adjacent sibling combinator (+). So it highlight only the div which is adjacent to it eg:http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/fb59w/. Use combinator what they want of own dependency

Answer (score 0):

Change the selector to this:

```
.a:hover + .boxhighlight {
    background-color:black;
}
```

The selector changes the styles of the element that has class `boxhighlight` that next to `.a` when hovered.

Comment: there are reasons why this way of styling is not used. in short, this is a bad practice

Comment: I think i typed the wrong code before but now corrected.