# Change table contents on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, hover

I have a table like this:

```
<div class="footer_row_3">
   <table class="tableA">
      <tr>
         <td><img class="popcorn" src="http://i.imgur.com/HUjq2Va.png"></td>
         <td><span class="statement">Lorem Ipsum</span></td>
         <td><img class="popcorn" src="http://i.imgur.com/HUjq2Va.png"></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

What I want to do is that when the mouse hovers over `tableA` at any location within `tableA`, the following two changes happen:

1. Popcorn images change to this image: `http://i.imgur.com/K29T3Fw.png`
2. The text color changes to red.

- It should have with a CSS 'fade' style `transition`, so that the contents fades into the updated style contents.
- BOTH changes mentioned above should happen when I hover `tableA` from any place within `tableA`.

I know how to individually change text and image on hover, but I don't know how to do it together for multiple items.

How can I achieve this effect ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: To be honest, no I didn't give it a try on my own. Normally I would, but this thing felt a bit more advanced for my level, which is why I didn't try much on my own in this case. Also, I've been coding for like 13+ hours straight in a stretch so I'm a bit lazy right now. Hope you don't mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
span{
    transition: color 2s ease;
}
.tableA:hover span{
    color:red;
}
```

**Plain Javascript** (option 1)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('tableA')[0].onmouseover = function () {
    var images = document.getElementsByClassName('popcorn');
    console.log(images);
    for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].src = 'http://i.imgur.com/K29T3Fw.png'
    }
};
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kbuY9/2/)**

---

**jQuery** (option 2)

```
$('.tableA').hover(function () {
    $('.popcorn').prop('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/K29T3Fw.png');
});
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kbuY9/1/)**

**EDIT:**

### **New demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WBcWj/)**

Comment: I don't mind using jQuery if needed, as I'm already using jQuery elsewhere. The image changes, but it does not revert back to the old one when the mouse goes away. Can you fix this ? Also the transition effect is not synchronized. The image changes immediately, while the text color changes gradually over 2 seconds. Can you have both things changing together, over a period of 2 seconds, and also change them back to the old version when the mouse goes away, again together, over a period of 2 seconds ?

Comment: The image change on mouseout is working, but the transition is still not synchronized. Can that be fixed too ?

Comment: @Ahmad, I added what you asked. Did this help?

Answer (score 0):

Hover and change of other elements data/ styles is possible if the one element is the child of other

Here's a possible direction you can proceed and it works

```
#parent_element:hover > child_element {
    //change your required styling or images
}
```

Heres the link

[Hover to change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867257/is-there-any-way-to-hover-over-one-element-and-effect-a-different-element)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
table.tableA:hover span.statement {
    color: red;
    -webkit-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
}

table.tableA:hover img.popcorn {   
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; 
}

table.tableA td:first-child, table.tableA td:last-child {
     background: url('http://i.imgur.com/K29T3Fw.png');
}
```

for better control and getting rid of first-child and last-child add classes to the tds.