# CSS hover code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make text appear when mouse hovers over  another text. FOr this I am using the following code:

```
<style>
#para1 {
    visibility:hidden;
}
#p2:hover, #para1 {
    visibility:visible;
}
</style>
</head>
<p id="para1">Hello World!</p>
<p id="p2">This paragraph is not affected by the style.</p>
```

This is however not working. Please suggest.

Comment: What effect do you want to achieve?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867257/is-there-any-way-to-hover-over-one-element-and-affect-a-different-element

Comment: Hi ALex, I want to show para1, when mouse is hovered over p2.

Answer (score 1):

**Using CSS3 properties on hover you you can select next element, This is called the adjacent sibling selector, and it is represented by a plus sign**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3Uf96/)**

**HTML**

```
<p id="para1">Hello World!</p>
<p id="p2">This paragraph is not affected by the style.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    visibility:hidden;
}
#para1 {
    visibility: visible;
}
#para1:hover + p {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using visibility try  operating by display:

```
#para1{display:none;}
#p2:hover + #para1{display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some simple jQuery (I see you have tagged it in this category)

```
$('#p2').hover(function() {
$('#para1').show
}, function() {
$('#para1').hide
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no previous sibling selector in CSS, so you'd have to use JavaScript for this. Try:

```
$('#p2').hover(
    function(){
        $('#para1').css('visibility','visible')},
    function(){
        $('#para1').css('visibility','hidden')
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nwy3H/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this 2 rules:

```
p {
    display:none;
}
#para1, #para1:hover + p {
    display: inline;
}
```

or this:

```
p {
    display:none;
}
#para1, #para1:hover + p {
    display: block;
}
```

If depends what kind of result do you want. You can try with jQuery too.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
#p2:hover #para1{
   visibility:visible;
 }
```

or:

```
#para1{
   display :none;
  }
#p2:hover #para1{
   display:block;
  }
```