# How can I make two boxes turn one color when you hover over either?

Tags: html, css

Currently, when you hover over the blue box both turn yellow, but when you hover over the red box, only it turns yellow.

I need both of them to turn yellow when you hover over either the blue, or the red.

This is as far as I have gotten:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style> 

                #one {
                    background-color: blue;
                    width: 50px;
                    height: 50px;
                    float: left;
                }
                #two {
                    background-color: red;
                    width: 50px;
                    height: 50px;
                    float: left;
                    margin-left: 100px;
                }

                #two:hover {
                    background-color: yellow;
                }
                #two:hover ~ #one {
                    background-color: yellow;
                }

                #one:hover {
                    background-color: yellow;
                }
                #one:hover ~ #two {
                    background-color: yellow;
                }

            </style>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div id="one"></div>
        <div id="two"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to hover over one element and affect a different element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867257/is-there-any-way-to-hover-over-one-element-and-affect-a-different-element). Another useful answer might be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered

Comment: In order to select a previous sibling, you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: what about placing them into the same container and set style for this container

Comment: @TylerH  pointer-events and hover can help here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwsuF , it even triggers bg parent only when child is hovered

Comment: @TylerH , forget it, the question had nothing to do with climbing up the DOM via CSS ...

Comment: @GCyrillus Changing the markup changes the game, of course :-)

Comment: @TylerH , oki : then no extra parent , just body .A container is a container ;) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yizaC

Comment: @GCyrillus I had forgotten for a moment about the ability to hover an an ancestor to effect a change in two descendant siblings, and was thinking only of a strict "previous sibling selector".

Comment: @TylerH same with me , this is what i understood in the first place untill he accepted an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/hmLbrouk/1/)**

just this

```
.container:hover div {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: exellent, how to make a big deal of a basic CSS rule and let everyone think it cannot be that ;) +1 of course

Answer (score 3):

here is solution without js

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CroaToa/hmLbrouk/2/)

Comment: .container:nth-child(1):hover div {
    background: yellow;
} you can avoid to use :nth-child(1) but just .container:hover div {
    background: yellow;
}

Comment: If #one, #two do not float, parent has no problem to wrap them, and result/effect is different: http://jsfiddle.net/hmLbrouk/3/

Answer (score 0):

Using `:before` to simulate a hovered div `#one`...
HTML stays the same

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/bj2148sL/)

**CSS**

```
#one {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
#two {
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#one:hover, #one:hover ~ #two, #two:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#two:before {
    content:'';
    display:none;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:-150px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#two:hover:before {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: But if blocks need move dinamicly? Responsive or fluid design?

Answer (score 0):

If you want hover to applied only when child are hovered, then pointer-events can be a way to do this: **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwsuF)**

your CSS turns to be more like :

```
#one {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
#two {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.parent {
  pointer-events:none;
  overflow:hidden;/* for float , for DEMO purpose to extend body or parent as there would be more content behind childs in real situation. */
}
.parent div {
  pointer-events:auto;
  cursor:pointer
}
.parent:hover div#one,
.parent:hover div#two
{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

How does this works ?

`pointer-events:none` , kills mouse events on parent. Reset to normal to childs.

If you hover a child, then the parent is hovered and the CSS rules `parent:hover` can be applied.