# Hovering and changing div lower down in DOM with css only?

Tags: css

If I have tabs like this in html:

```
<ul class="qtabs">
    <li><a href="{show tab1}">tab 1 title</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="{show tab2}">tab 2 title</a></li>
    <li><a href="{show tab3}">tab 3 title</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-container">

    <div id="tab1">
        <div class="tab-content">text, text, text, text....</div>
    </div>

    <div id="tab2" style="display:none;">
        <div class="tab-content">text, text, text, text....</div>
    </div>

    <div id="tab2" style="display:none;">
        <div class="tab-content">text, text, text, text....</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Is it possible with **CSS only** to make hover-effect (change textcolor of .tab-content for the tab that user is hovering over ? (it's ok if it only works with css3)

**Possible duplciate?**
[Is there any way to hover over one element and affect a different element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867257)

Kind of, but nothing has happened in 4 years then? :-)

Comment: I don't think you can with an HTML structure like yours. You could if you had [descendant or adjacent elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867257/is-there-any-way-to-hover-over-one-element-and-affect-a-different-element)

Comment: Can you please clarify? Are you trying to change the colour of `tab-content` when you hover the appropriate `li` in `qtabs` or change the colour of `tab-content` when you hover the `#tab1`

Comment: Clarification: I want to change change the colour of tab-content when I hover the appropriate li in qtabs

Comment: I think this is the closest you can get https://jsfiddle.net/0kn15mdc/ based on @musefan s answer and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling

Comment: @forgetso: Nice idea! [this takes it a step further](https://jsfiddle.net/0kn15mdc/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get exactly what you want unfortunately, but perhaps this is close enough for what you need.

If you allow the hover to work on `.qtabs` instead of each individually `li`. Then you can use a combination of the sibling selector and the standard descendant selector to meet your needs:

```
.qtabs:hover ~ .tab-container .tab-content {
    color:red;
}
```

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/efhfe2x2/)

The benefit of this approach is that it requires no changes to your existing HTML structure, and without JavaScript which I assume you are trying to avoid for whatever reason.

---

Need each tab page to have a different colour?

Then why not try our [new and improved version](https://jsfiddle.net/efhfe2x2/1/)

Comment: This is close enough I think. Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to check the children of `ul` to see which is active and then reverse back up the DOM to get to `tab-content`. This is how you could write that rule...

```
ul li.active:hover  + .tab-container #tab1 .tab-content {color:#f00;}
```

**HOWEVER it is not currently possible to do this in CSS.** 
This behaviour is frequently requested and is more commonly known as a "parent selector" however, .

If you can change your markup and maybe include something on the `ul` which will enable you to identify the tab then you could do something like this:

```
ul.activeTab1:hover + .tab-container #tab1 .tab-content {color:#f00;}
ul.activeTab2:hover + .tab-container #tab2 .tab-content {color:#f00;}
```

which would be almost what I think you are after..

http://jsfiddle.net/qdgtx4jc/