# Change other table element's style after hover

Tags: html, css

Here is my table: (I know I had to use divs instead of tables)

```html
<table class="table-fill">
  <thead>
    <tr class="">
      <th class="text-top">
        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i></th>
      <th class="text-top">Service & Support</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-hover">
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-right-alt2"></span></td>
      <td class="text-left">TableData1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-right-alt2"></span></td>
      <td class="text-left">TableData2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-right-alt2"></span></td>
      <td class="text-left">TableData3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-right-alt2"></span></td>
      <td class="text-left">TableData4 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"></td>
      <td class="text-left"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to have another background and color for the .text-top class when hovering over .text-left.The table must also have a different box-shadow.
Here my CSS:

```css
.text-left:hover .table-fill {
    box-shadow: 0 26px 74px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
}

.text-left:hover .text-top {
   background:#fff;
   color:#4E5066;
}
```

I've tried `.text-left:hover ~ .table-fill`, `.text-left:hover + .table-fill` and `.text-left:hover > .table-fill` but this didn't work.

I also looked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling), [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867257/is-there-any-way-to-hover-over-one-element-and-affect-a-different-element), but this was not fixing my problem.

I want to avoid jQuery if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not change the style on table hover itself, since all of your content has text-left class, its like hovering anywhere inside the table. This is just my suggestion.

```css
.table-fill:hover {

  box-shadow: 0 26px 74px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);

}


.table-fill:hover .text-top {

  background: #fff;
  color: #4E5066;

}
```

```html
<table class="table-fill">
  <thead>
    <tr class="">
      <th class="text-top">
        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
      </th>
      <th class="text-top">Service & Support</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-hover">
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-right-alt2"></span>
      </td>
      <td class="text-left">TableData1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-right-alt2"></span>
      </td>
      <td class="text-left">TableData2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-right-alt2"></span>
      </td>
      <td class="text-left">TableData3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-right-alt2"></span>
      </td>
      <td class="text-left">TableData4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"></td>
      <td class="text-left"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.table-filled` and `.text-top` is neither a sibling or descendant of `.text-left` so this will not work. jQuery is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

### This is my solution:

Change the activation to be **.table-fill** instead of **.text-left** like the following:

```
.table-fill:hover .text-top {
  background:#fff;
  color:#4E5066;
}
.table-fill:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 26px 74px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
}
```

Hope it creates the desired effect