# Menu item hover into <section> border;

Tags: html, css

How do I draw a border over my section while mouse is over any navigation element `<a>` etc ?
I were trying to find solution but none of + . ~ work for me.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">BAC</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CAD</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">EEE</a></li>
        <li class="image">
          <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section class="content">
    CONTENT
  </section>
</div>
```

Could someone share some css code to do this? That would be awesome !

Solution : Use jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
            $('li').hover(function() {
                $('.content').css('outline', 'solid 5px');
        }, function() {
            $('.content').css('outline', '');
      });
    });
});
```

Thats my script, but you can find alternative @below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use javascript for this. Css can only do it if the section is a decendent of the anchor tag or is a sibling. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867257/is-there-any-way-to-hover-over-one-element-and-affect-a-different-element) for the explaination.

I used some jquery to do what you need. Tweak it as you like.

```js
$(function(){
  //On hover of nav anchor add red border
  $('nav a').hover(function(){
    $('.content').css('border', '1px solid red');
  });
  
  //Clear the css we added
  $('nav a').mouseout(function(){
   $('.content').css('border', '');
  })
});
```

```css
#test:hover + .content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <nav>
      These will only work with some javascript/jquery.
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">BAC</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CAD</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">EEE</a></li>
        <li class="image">
          <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- This works with css. + . ~ only work if the tags are siblings, decendents etc -->
  <a href="#" id="test">This works with css because it's a sibling</a>
  <section class="content">
    CONTENT
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats the solution. Thanks you sir.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I draw a border over my section while mouse is over any navigation element  etc ? I were trying to find solution but none of + . ~ work for me.

With current CSS you can only select to the right or downward, but not to the left or upwards in the DOM. (See also: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector))

Both `+` and `~` work based on a sibling relationship between elements. So this can only work, if you want it to react on hovering the whole `header` element, because the section is a sibling of only that element.

```css
header:hover + section {
  outline:5px solid;
}

/* optional: */
/*
header {
  display:inline-block;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">BAC</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CAD</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">EEE</a></li>
        <li class="image">
          <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section class="content">
    CONTENT
  </section>
</div>
```

If you want to limit the area that triggers the effect, you can make the header inline-block - then most of the space to the right of the items won't react to the mouse cursor. To fine-tune the effect to the desired boundaries, you can play with the margins and padding of the elements involved.

Comment: Thanks for that. You just proved that it was still "do-able?" without jQuery. Have a nice day/night :)

Answer (score -1):

Target the section after the hover.

```
nav li:hover section {
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thats not the solution, i've already tried it and it doesnt work.