# How do I override TR with an element inside TD with CSS?

Tags: css

I have this table that I want to change color when hovered, but will also change different color when a link is inside the TD.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hovering this part will make the whole TR bgcolor red</td>
        <td>Hovering this part will make the whole TR bgcolor red</td>
        <td>Hovering this part will make the whole TR bgcolor red</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Hovering this part will make the whole TR bgcolor red</td>
        <td>Hovering this part will make the whole TR bgcolor red</td>
        <td>Hovering this part will make the whole TR bgcolor red</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Hovering this part will make the whole TR bgcolor red</td>
        <td>Hovering this part will make the whole TR bgcolor red</td>
        <td>
            <a>HOVERING THIS LINK WILL MAKE WHOLE TR BG COLOR BLUE</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried in CSS

```
table tr:hover:not(table td a) {
    background-color: red !important;
}

table tr:hover{ 
    background-color: blue;
}
```

But I have no luck.
Is this possible without using Javascript/Jquery?

Comment: it's not possible with CSS alone, since CSS can't select parent elements

Comment: this could eventually be a fix ? https://jsfiddle.net/8h6u711v/3/

Answer (score 1):

you may use pseudo elements layed under `tr` that will be used to draw the backgrounds.

`z-index` will manage to pile them under contents.

example:

```css
table tr {
  position: relative;
}

table tr a:before,
tr:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  float:left;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}
table tr:hover:before {
  background: red;  
}

table tr a:hover:before {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: blue;
}

/*and  eventually: */a {display:block;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.0001);}a:hover {color:white;}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hovering this part will make the whole TR bgcolor red</td>
        <td>Hovering this part will make the whole TR bgcolor red</td>
        <td>Hovering this part will make the whole TR bgcolor red</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Hovering this part will make the whole TR bgcolor red</td>
        <td>Hovering this part will make the whole TR bgcolor red</td>
        <td>Hovering this part will make the whole TR bgcolor red</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Hovering this part will make the whole TR bgcolor red</td>
        <td>Hovering this part will make the whole TR bgcolor red</td>
        <td>
            <a>HOVERING THIS LINK WILL MAKE WHOLE TR BG COLOR BLUE</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unusual that you do it without some javascript.
But if you really want to do it, you can check this questions out and try it by yourself.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867257/is-there-any-way-to-hover-over-one-element-and-affect-a-different-element)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling)

Hope I could help...

Comment: those questions/answers are about sibblings, not parents. it won't help :( Your answer looks much more like a comment than else ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus Can't comment because of my reputation points :) But thanks for correcting my answer. Obviously you're right ;)