# How to make a hover effect for pseudo elements?

Tags: css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I have a this setup:

```
<div id="button">Button</div>
```

and this for CSS:

```
#button {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-indent: 20px;
    width: 12%;
}

#button:before {
    background-color: blue;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
```

Is there a way to give the pseudo element a hover effect such as `#button:before:hover {...}` and is it also possible to get the pseudo element to hover in response to another element being hovered like so: `#button:hover #button:before {...}`? CSS only would be nice, but also jQuery is fine too.

Comment: there is a way to hover one element and affect another(purely with css): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462360/css-hover-one-element-effect-for-multiple-elements my question relates to pseudo elements though

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You can change the pseudo-element based on hover of the parent:

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5WV75/)**

```
#button:before {
    background-color: blue;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}

#button:hover:before {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```css
#button {    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-indent: 20px;
    width: 12%;}

#button:before { background-color: blue;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;}

#button:hover:before { background-color: red;}
```

```html
<div id="button">Button</div>
```

Comment: Note - `:before` would require IE8+.

Comment: True, left that out since the question was specifically about `:before`.

Comment: Won't that hover then be applied to the button and not the pseudo-element `:before`? I mean, if you want the pseudo element to change when only the pseudo element is hovered, but not when the rest of the button is hovered?

Comment: @jgivoni This will apply to either the element or the before.  You can't apply a hover to just the pseudo element.

Comment: this answer is wrong, as it is not possible to give :hover to pseudo elements, here you are giving the :hover to the parent element which was not the question tbh

Comment: @MaximilianKöhler If you run the demo you will see it applies the hover effects to the before element, they just only happen *on* hover of the parent (which is how hover works).

Comment: @James Montagne Can you check this and suggests to me how can I achieve it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66923436/on-hover-after-element-move-to-current-div

Answer (score 41):

To clarify, you **CAN NOT** give `:hover` to a pseudo element. There's no such thing as `::after:hover` in CSS as of 2018.

Answer (score 11):

`#button:hover:before` will change the pseudo-element in response to the button being hovered.  If you want to do anything nontrivial to the pseudo-element only, however, you'd be better off putting an actual element into your HTML.  Pseudo-elements are rather limited.

While CSS won't let you style elements based on elements that come after them, it is usually possible to rig something with the same basic effect by putting :hover on a parent node, i.e.:

```
<div id="overbutton">
    <div id="buttonbefore"></div>
    <div id="button"></div>
</div>

#overbutton {
    margin-top: 25px;
    position: relative;
}

#buttonbefore {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    top: -25px;
}

#overbutton:hover #buttonbefore {
    // set styles that should apply to buttonbefore on button hover
}

#overbutton:hover #buttonbefore:hover {
    // unset styles that should apply on button hover
    // set styles that should apply to buttonbefore on buttonbefore hover
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its just for design purposes I think its better to create Pseudo-Elements on either side of the Rectangle Box and to keep the HTML as simple as possible:

HTML:

```
 <body>
    <div class="tabStyle">Rectangle</div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
 .tabStyle {
        border-style:solid;
        border-color: #D8D8D8;
        background : #D8D8D8;
        width:200px;
        height:93px;
        color: #000;
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
        left: 49px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .tabStyle:hover {
        background : #000;
        border-color: #000;
    }
    .tabStyle:hover::before {
        border-color: transparent #000 #000 transparent;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0px 0px 100px 50px;
    }
    .tabStyle:hover::after {
        border-color: transparent transparent #000 #000;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0px 50px 100px 0px;
    }
    .tabStyle::after {
        border-color: transparent transparent #D8D8D8 #D8D8D8;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0px 50px 100px 0px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -4px;
        left:101%;
        content:"";
    }
    .tabStyle::before {
        border-color: transparent #D8D8D8 #D8D8D8 transparent;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0px 0px 100px 50px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -4px;
        right: 101%;
        content:"";
    }
```

I've modified the CSS and the result can be seen below:

http://jsfiddle.net/a3ehz5vu/