# Perspective focus (grey out other items and highlight current) for menu items with CSS

Tags: css, colors, menuitem

I have a menu list as below:

```
<div id="menubar">
    <ul class="menulist">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is that initially, the font-color for the menu items is dark grey. But when user hovers over any menu item, that particular item remains dark grey but rest of the items turn light-grey.

I have following CSS.

```
    #menubar a {
        color: #202021;
        display: block;
        padding: 6px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #menubar a:hover {
        display: block;
        padding: 6px;
        background-color: #97979B;
        border-radius: 3px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #menubar .menulist:hover {
        color: #747478;
    }
```

But `color` given in `.menulist:hover` is not applied to menu items other than hovered item, while properties other than `color` is applied to **rest** of the menu items when I hover on any menu item. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462360/css-hover-one-element-effect-for-multiple-elements) SO question which had somewhat similar requirement.

How can I get this behavior with pure CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your two selectors as follows:

```
#menubar .menulist:hover  a {
    color: #747478;
}​

#menubar .menulist:hover a:hover {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: #97979B;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/GMNXa/)**

---

A quick word on the second selector `#menubar .menulist:hover a:hover`:

Normally, this is only necessary to apply your css because you don't change the color of the anchor when `a:hover`:

```
#menubar .menulist:hover a {
    color: #747478;
}​

#menubar a:hover {
    ...
    /* no color change here */
}
```

If you decide to change the color of the anchor that is hovered though, it will not be applied because the selector `#menubar .menulist:hover a` has a higher specificity than `#menubar a:hover`

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/LmRjV/)**

Making the second selector `#menubar .menulist:hover a:hover` ensures it has a higher specificity than `#menubar .menulist:hover a` and rules overrides correctly

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/7FLPB/)**

**Further reading:**

- [CSS Specificity And Inheritance](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/)
- [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! the `#menubar .menulist:hover a:hover` is very new for me.

Comment: I've added some explanations to explain why the second selector.