# change body background image/gradient on hovering other elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the background image/gradient of the body while hovering on a div (id="above"), I follow the way they do in another post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462360/css-hover-one-element-effect-for-multiple-elements) but it doesn't seems to work

css

```
body {
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, ...);
}

.about:hover body{
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, ...); // new gradient
}
```

html

```
<body>
    <div class="about">
        <h1 id="title">About</h1>
        <div>
            <p id="about">stuff</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This has no effect, I even try to test if this works by changing the title style to italic while hovering, still no use

```
.about:hover h1.title {
    font-weight: italic;
}
```

Is that the way I use it is wrong or there is something else, anyone can help?

Comment: CSS works from parent to children, you cannot reference a parent element from a child.

Comment: `font-weight: italic;` is invalid it should be `font-style:italic`

Comment: Plus, there is no `h1.title`, there is only `h1#title`.

Comment: @TheZ Thanks! But any idea how to reference back to the parents? Is there anyway at all?

Comment: @ryf9059 In CSS I would say no, Javascript could do it. CSS is as fast as it is because it doesn't ever have to look back up the hierarchy, it only applies downward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with CSS (no javascript), you can do a trick with `z-index`:

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nCyJ4/

Or, in your case, http://jsfiddle.net/nCyJ4/1/ :

HTML:

```
<div class="initial background" id="bg0"></div>
<div class="about bgwrapper">
    <h1 id="title">About</h1>
    <div>
        <p id="about">stuff</p>
    </div>
    <div id="bg1" class="background"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;left:0;
    width:100%;height:100%;
    display:none;
    z-index:-1;
}
.bgwrapper:hover>.background,.initial.background{
    display:block;
}
.initial.background:hover{
    display:block!important;
}
.background:hover{
    display:none!important;
}
#bg0{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #FF0000 0%, #FF9900 10%, #FFFF00 16.666%, #CCFF00 20%, #32FF00 30%, #00FF00 33.333%, #00FF65 40%, #00FFFF 50%, #00FFFF 50%, #0065FF 60%, #0000FF 66.666%, #3300FF 70%, #CB00FF 80%, #FF00FF 83.333%, #FF0098 90%, #FF0004 100%);

}

#bg1{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left center, #FF0000, #000000) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `body` is not a descendant of `div.about`, it cannot be targeted like that.  You could use a little JavaScript to achieve the effect you need though.

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, ...);
}

body.hover {
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, ...); // new gradient
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('about')[0].onmouseover = function () {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className += ' hover';
}
document.getElementsByClassName('about')[0].onmouseout = function () {
    var n = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    n.className = n.className.replace('hover', '');
}
```

Comment: I actually want to use the CSS because I want to combine it with the newest transition technique so my background gradient to change smoothly, will javascript achieve this effect?

Comment: You could animate the change with jQuery... but perhaps your best method is to alter your markup instead of scripting, as @Oriol described in his/her answer.