# Change background image on link hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, mouseover

So I have this problem, which I couldn't find, even though I did a thorough websearch.

I am making my portfolio, and the background is a picture of a woman, located in the center.
On the left I have a nav bar with link to other pages.

What I basicly want, is the background image to change when I hover over one of the links.
Whether it's through CSS, Javascript or JQuery, I want to know if it's possible.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: 
Sorry, I'll try to provide the best I can.

### HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
```

```
<div class="header">/jacob gerlif pilegaard/</div>
<div class="underheader">portfolio</div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html"">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul> 
 <h1>About me...</h1>
 <p> bla bla bla bla bla</p>
 <div id="circles"></div>
```

This is the basic html. The id="baggrund" is the image I want to change to something else.

### CSS

```
#baggrund {
background-image: url(images/laerkeryg.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 720px;
height: 394px;
position: absolute;
left: 805px;
top: 10%;}
```

This is the CSS for the image I want to have replaced.

### Jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#first").hover(function () {
    $("baggrund").css("background-image", 'url("images/Kat5.jpg")');
});
});
```

Hope this helps, and thanks again.

Comment: Please provide relevant HTML/CSS/JS demonstrating what you have tried - and yes - to answer your question, this is possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940645/change-body-background-image-gradient-on-hovering-other-elements

Comment: Here the answer of you question : Yes it is possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generic jquery answer to your question:

```
$('a.class').on('mousein', function(){
   $('#portfolio').css('background-image', 'url("other.jpg")');
});
$('a.class').on('mouseout', function(){, function(){
  $('#portfolio').css('background-image', 'url("woman.jpg")');
});
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for. Thank you very much. Seems as if my jquery library was not installed correctly among other things. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here's a rough example via JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dGnMX/

```
<nav>
     <a id="first">Link 1</a>
     <a id="second">Link 1</a>
     <a id="third">Link 1</a>
    </nav>

$("#first").click(function () {

    $("body").css("background-image", 'url("http://static.bbc.co.uk/solarsystem/img/ic/640/collections/space_exploration/space_exploration_large.jpg")');

});



$("#second").click(function () {

    $("body").css("background-image", 'url("http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02179/Milky-Way_2179177b.jpg")');

});

$("#third").click(function () {

    $("body").css("background-image", 'url("http://www.thatsreallypossible.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Space-Colonialisation.jpg")');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript to do that, you can use `:hover` pseudo-class on pure CSS 2.1:

```
#baggrund:hover {
    background-image: url('images/Kat5.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's perfect tested solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('a.class').hover(

           function () {
              $('#portfolio').css('background-image', 'url("other.jpg")');
           }, 

           function () {
              $('#portfolio').css('background-image', 'url("woman.jpg")');
           }
        );

     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution i've come across by changing background-image position on hover

```
<!--HTML-->
<div class="twitter1">
    <a href="https://twitter.com">
    </a>
</div>

/*CSS*/
.twitter1 a{
display: block;
background: url(12.\ Sprites.png) 0px 0px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 50px;
height: 47px;
}

.twitter1 a:hover{
background: url(12.\ Sprites.png) 0px 52px;
}
```