# Change body background on inferior div:hover

Tags: css, html, hover

I'm trying to get the background of the body to change when a division within is hovered. In reality I want to have the background blurred with a CSS3 transition, but for the purpose of this, just going to get the colour to change

http://jsfiddle.net/5dm6m/

```
<body>
<div id="x"></div>
<div id="y"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    background: #0f0;
}

#x{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #f00;
}

#y{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #00f;
}

#y:hover body{
    background: #f0f;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change body bgcolor on hovering a div, using CSS only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039723/change-body-bgcolor-on-hovering-a-div-using-css-only)

Comment: Not a duplicate as the solution refers to an adjacent division rather than a parent.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940645/change-body-background-image-gradient-on-hovering-other-elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QRrnj/)
But i think that you should do it with jQuery better.

```
$('#y').hover(function(){
    $('body').css('background', '#f0f');
},function(){
    $('body').css('background', '');
});
```

[see on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SYbKW/2/)