# CSS: Hover over one element, effect another?

Tags: css, hover

Please see the page here:

```
http://176.32.230.17/printingcrazy.com/branding-services
```

I'm trying to achieve a hover effect, so if you hover over any of the services listed, the relevant image will have a border for example.

And if you hover over the Image, the relevant text will change color.

Elements on the left are in a separate parent to the ones on the right.

Yes I have seen [CSS: Hover one element, effect for multiple elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462360/css-hover-one-element-effect-for-multiple-elements)  and have tried everything, but cannot get it to apply to my circumstances.

Any help would really be appreciated!

```
<div class="servicepage">

<div class="serviceleft">
<img src="/digitalprint.jpg">
<img src="/dyesub.jpg">
</div>

<div class="serviceright">
<ul>
<li>
<h3>Digital Print</h3>
</li>
<li>
<h3>Dye Sublimation</h3>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code instead of a link to it.

Comment: Edited to include simplified code, apologies.

Comment: This cannot be done with CSS. You must use jQuery/JavaScript if you want to keep current HTML markup.

Comment: Really? :(  Ok... i dont have a clue how I would do this with jQuery or JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is a simplified example. hope it helps you get started.

basically we are setting callback functions when the mouse is hovered and left on the `div` foo. And in those functions we are changing the css properties of the `img`, in this case, adding a `border` and removing it.

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/YC2tg/

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".foo").hover(function () {
        $(".bar").css("border", "5px red solid");
    });
    $(".foo").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".bar").css("border", "none");
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="foo">HOVER HERE</div>
<img class="bar" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
```

Comment: This is great. Can we do the same between parent and child? (i.e. Hover on child to change parents border.)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this.

HTML:

```
<div class="servicepage">
    <div class="serviceleft">
        <img class="digitalprint" src="/digitalprint.jpg">
        <img class="dyesub" src="/dyesub.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="serviceright">
        <ul>
            <li class="digitalprint">
                 <h3>Digital Print</h3>
            </li>
            <li class="dyesub">
                 <h3>Dye Sublimation</h3>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".serviceleft > img").hover(

function () {
    var imgclass = $(this).attr("class");
    $("li." + imgclass).css("color", "red");
},

function () {
    var imgclass = $(this).attr("class");
    $("li." + imgclass).css("color", "black");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to reproduce code for your markup on the site, and this jQuery code should work, just copy/paste it on your site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".serviceright h3").mouseenter(function(){
            var indexH3 = $(this).parent().index();
            $(".serviceleft .spotlight").eq(indexH3).addClass("border");
        });
        $(".serviceright h3").mouseleave(function(){
            $(".serviceleft .spotlight").removeClass("border");
        });

        $(".serviceleft .spotlight").mouseenter(function(){
            var indexA = $(this).index();
            $(".serviceright h3").eq(indexA).addClass("redtext");
        });
        $(".serviceleft .spotlight").mouseleave(function(){
            $(".serviceright h3").removeClass("redtext");
        });
    });
</script>
```

You must add some CSS classes for hover effect, for example

```
.border {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.redtext {
    color: red;
}
```

Set properties for hover effect, and if you need to rename those classes, change those names in jQuery code also.

And here is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RVDhC/)**

Comment: Thank you. I managed to do it using @btevfik 's code, but it meant 4 lines for each service = 36 lines of code.   I shall try and replace with yours when i get time!!

Comment: Ok, try btefvik's code. Just to make clear, this code is complete, you don't have to change it.