# CSS hover 2 another elements (and another atributes)

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, hyperlink, hover

I have link `<a></a>` and inside this link i have canvas and normal text.
Both elements have setted opacity (over rgba()) on 50% visibility.
With hovering this link i would like to change visibility property on 100% by both elements.

Problem is:
in canvas i need to change background-color.
With that text inside link i need change color.
link looks like:

```
<a href="" class="table_link">
  <canvas class="canvas_table_item"></canvas>
  Chair
</a>
```

if i put both in 1 selector:

```
.content_table *:hover{
   color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
   background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

it change the background color of the text (link) as well..
I need change background-color ONLY on the canvas and color on the text (it can be changed on canvas as well).
Is there way how to achieve that only with CSS or do i realy need to use javascript?

ANSWER IN HERE: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Yck/)

SOLUTION IS ADD  AND INSIDE THIS THE LINK TEXT LIKE IN HERE:

```
<a href="" class="table_link">
  <canvas class="canvas_table_item"></canvas>
  <span>
     Chair
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: So use one selector for all the shared changes, and a separate, specific selector, for changes specific to one element.

Comment: this is not solution. because if you hover only the text i am not able to get that background on the canvas. And that is what i am asking about. If there is way how to select that canvas background color. something like canvas_table_item.background-color:..... but i think i will be able do that only with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Yck/)

Just add these CSS rules:

```
a.table_link {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
a:hover > canvas {
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

a:hover > * { color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); }
```

Comment: that is exactly what i need and what i had..i am wonder, why in my code it doesnt work..Ok, nevermind. Thanks for reply, marking as answer and going to search the problem on my side. Thanks

Comment: AH! the <span> was a solution!! it need to add the <span> around the text inside link..

Comment: Sure! Always when you need to add text to your markup, add the `span` element.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462360/css-hover-one-element-effect-for-multiple-elements) that have the answer.

Try this:

`*:hover .content_table{
    color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}`

Comment: You can perform this with CSS, javascript isn't really needed