# CSS Controlling things with other things

Tags: css

I'm  **new**  to the world of CSS3 / HTML5, and I want to do something but I didn't know how to do it. I'd like to control an element with another element, for example, when .A is hovered, .B goes blue. Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: Hover one element, effect for multiple elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462360/css-hover-one-element-effect-for-multiple-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS selectors. If B is a child of A, it's very easy: you can do
`#A:hover > #B { ... }`

Otherwise, you can use other particular selectors, like `~` and `+`.

Take a look here: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='a'></div>
<div class='b'></div>

<style>
    .a {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background: blue;
    }

    .b {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background: green;
    }

    .a:hover + .b {
        background: red;
    }
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vgoLx7z0/

Here's a fiddle for it, although I do recommend using jQuery for it anyway

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is... But with some conditions.

You have several css relative selectors, but they only target for following sibilings, and children.

Some examples:

- `.a:hover + .b` - selects the `.b` element that immediatly follows a hovered `.a` as a sibiling.
- `.a:hover ~ .b` - selects the `.b` element that follows at any distance a hovered `.a` as a sibiling.
- `.a:hover > .b` - selects the `.b` element that is a direct child of a hovered `.a`.
- `.a:hover .b` - selects the `.b` element that is a child at any nested level of a hovered `.a`.

There are many other relational selectors, you can find out more: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/

**Be aware that there are no parent selector, neither previous sibiling selectors... Only followers**

For a more varied kind of selection, you'll have to look into Javascript manipulation, so you can navigate through elements any way you want!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to do this? Yes, but there are a lot of limitations.

First of all, you need to define the "action", which is done using CSS [pseudo-classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp). Pseudo-classes (and CSS in general) aren't really action-oriented. In fact, the only real action would be the `:hover` pseudo class (and the `:focus`, which is triggered when you put your typing cursor in a form field).

Next, you'll need to define your target element. To do this, you'll need to use [child and sibling selectors](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/). There's a handful of these, but they're all very specific and not very flexible. They'll do things like "select the first paragraph tag that is a direct child of the div tag which has a particular id". For example, if you have the following HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="">Link</a>
        <ul style="display:none">
            <li><a href="">Sub-menu item</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li>
</ul>
```

You can use the following CSS to make the sub-navigation visible when you hover over its parent:

```
#menu li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

This example finds the `ul` element which is a direct child of the `li` element which is being hovered over. See the link I posted above for an in-depth exploration of sibling and child selectors.

When you need to do something more complicated or more flexible (for example, changing an element based on a click instead of hover), you will need to use JavaScript or jQuery, or some similar scripting solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `:hover` pseudo selector.

> The :hover pseudo-class applies while the user designates an element
>   with a pointing device, but does not necessarily activate it.

[W3 Definition](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:hover)
You would use :hover like:

```
.a:hover .b{
background:red;
}
```

This selects a element with the class `.b` inside a element with the class `.a` like so:

```
 <div class="a">
    Hover over me!
    <div class="b">
    I will turn red when you hover over my parent.
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also select direct siblings:

```
.a:hover + .b{
    background:red;
    }

 <div class="a">
    Hover over me!
 </div>
 <div class="b">
 I will turn red when you hover over .a.
 </div>
```

Or indirect siblings:

```
.a:hover ~ .b button{
        background:red;
        }



      <div class="a">
            Hover over me!
         </div>
         <div class="b">
         <button>
         I will turn red when you hover over .a.
         </button>
         </div>
```

But, you cannot select parents or sibling above the hovered element.
[JSFiddle Demo of CSS selection](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/402kt4a6/)
The other option is to use JavaScript onmouseover & onmouseout:

```
<div id="parent" >Lorem ipsum dolor...<h1>
    <div id="b" onmouseover="document.getElementById('parent').style.backgroundColor='red';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('parent').style.backgroundColor='white';">Hover over me and change my parent!</div></h1>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/402kt4a6/1/)
You could also use JQuery hover(), but that is really not needed for this small a operation.

Comment: `+` is an adjacency selector, not a sibling selector. i believe you're thinking of `>`.

Comment: sorry, i confused sibling for child. ignore that.